# Who is user####### and why has (s)he given 871 downvotes in just 17 days as a user?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-user

Given that some of us have been getting uncommented downvotes on our answers - I alone have had 7 in the past two days - I'd like to know a little more about this user and the faults (s)he apparently sees in our answers (and questions).

Comment: I'm Grace Note, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. I've erased all of the comments in this thread because it was primarily a whole lot of hostile speculation. I cleared the whole lot so that I can end on a simple note - if you have concerns about the behavior of a specific individual, public callouts are generally rather inappropriate. The proper course of action would be to either reach the moderators via flag, or contact the team via the "contact us" form at the bottom, and we'll investigate and contact the user should our investigations turn up anything to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A user can reveal as much as they want about themselves, and I think it is appropriate to respect the boundaries of what a user reveals about themself. If someone suspects a user to violate the rules, contacting the moderators is a prudent thing to do.

There have been several meta discussions on downvoting without accompanying comments, and the majority position seems to be that this is legitimate. For the point of view of someone who "downvote[s] quite generously, and rarely comment[s]", see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11522/21674).

Comment: I accepted the answer to this question because, believe it or not, I agree with it.  I posted the question because I wanted to understand why someone might vote like that.  The question has been answered.  As far as any nefarious purposes I had in asking the question: yes, I unfairly targeted this user.  The site allowed me to do that because this user's stats are public knowledge for all of us.  If the user felt put upon or embarrassed by this question, well, again, I apologize.  On the other hand, the discussion in the comments, while unsavory at times, was useful.

Comment: Please keep in mind that @BillDubuque and I have been unfairly targeted as well by someone who understands how the site works.  Obvious downvoting patterns get reversed thankfully, but targeted patterns, say, a few questions per day, spread out a couple at a time, do not get reversed.  While folks agree that this is a bad thing, the consensus seems to be that changes which could reverse such downvoting may do more harm than good.  Fine.  But in that case, I and others will work within the system against these irritants that devalue the site.