# Is it appropriate to downvote answers for the sake of deleting a question?

Tags: discussion, closing, down-votes, deletion

I have noticed that sometimes answers are downvoted in order to cause the automatic deletion of a question by the community user. In particular, there are closed questions with $1$-point answers - when the answer(s) are downvoted to $0$, they are then eligible for automatic deletion, which can only be undone by the moderators.

This was briefly discussed in [a comment thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15028/i-miss-10-rep-points#comment56691_15028) on a related meta question, but I would like to know what the community's feeling on this issue is in a more general sense. The vote total on Bill Dubuque's comment opposing this practice would seem to indicate that there are numerous people who disagree with this.

Personally, I believe that answers which are on-topic and mathematically valid should never be downvoted, regardless of the question quality; this does have the (perhaps unfortunate) side effect of preventing low-quality questions from being deleted.

---

**Edited**, $15$ hours after the original post; for the sake of noting the vote counts before this substantial change, the question is currently at $+5/-1$. Note that all the answers (except for Thomas's answer) were received *before* the substantial change to the question, and responded to the abstract issue.

This question was motivated by the actions of a single user, who is now making a large-scale effort to remove old questions that do not meet various quality standards. For example, all of these questions had close votes initiated by [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/this-is-much-healthier), and were subsequently deleted automatically due to $0$-score answers with $1$ upvote and $1$ downvote:

- [506593](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506593/calculus-derivatives-using-the-formal-definition-tangent-lines)
- [506396](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506396/matrix-squaring-identities)
- [505529](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505529/perpendicular-line-differential-cal)
- [505115](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505115/when-throwing-3-die-what-is-the-probability-of-getting-any-given-number-1-6)
- [501547](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501547/solving-problems-invovling-quadratic-equations-cubes)

and so on; other examples are 501467, 500197, 499054, 498085, 497807, 497583, 495832, 495732 and 495710, all of which were removed during the latest round of autodeletions. I am breaching the usual convention of no-naming on meta because the user has already given an answer to this question, stating that this is an action they regularly carry out; see also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13931/why-is-the-close-vote-review-flooded-with-old-questions/13932#13932).

I consider this behaviour to be abusive and gaming the automated deletion process in order to remove *large* amounts of content from the site. It circumvents the fact that the privilege of casting deletion votes is limited to the most experienced users of the site, and I think that many of the close-voters on these questions (myself included) would have seriously reconsidered the votes if they knew the ultimate fate of these answers.

---

**Edit**, part $2$, at the suggestion of This is much healthier. As Healthier points out in a comment below, a network-wide update means that these deletions are no longer irreversible - the posts automatically deleted by the Community user can be undeleted by non-moderator users. Although I feel this is a step in the right direction, I don't believe that this substantially changes any of the points I've made in this question; it would still take a large-scale coordinated effort by users who can cast undelete votes in order to counter the voting actions of one single user. Considering the hundreds of questions involved here, I do not believe this to be feasible.

Comment: It might be relevant to observe that it can only be relevant if OP of question did not accept. It might also be relevant that answers in situation where this could be relevant sometimes had gotten somehow sort of pitty upvote to prevent repeated bumping. (The 'might' is not rhetorical, it also might be irrelevant to some.)

Comment: No downvoting to delete questions is perfectly ok, in fact must be encouraged

Comment: @Zlatan Why do you believe that? Having joined only $7$ days ago, do you really think you have enough experience to understand all of the issues involved in the complex dynamics of this site?

Comment: @T.Bongers There are better examples of deleted answer - see my answer. Please feel free to add them above.

Comment: Please explain why it is gaming the automated process (also see my comment on Hurkly's answer). I can see that somebody does not like it and I do not consider it a good idea, but I fail to see how it is gaming the process.

Comment: @quid It circumvents the (apparent) design of the downvote vs. close vs. deletion system; being able to trigger a specific deletion vote is reserved to only the most experienced site users. The sheer volume of these deletions also seems to be substantially more than was intended; by proceeding in such a manner, a single user can cause $50$ questions to be deleted per day. It would take $3$ trusted users to delete a mere $30$.

Comment: @quid Because anyone with a few sockpuppets and half-decent programming skills can easily manage to force the Community user to delete any threads that they do not like, and the community has no way to undelete them without the help of moderators. Do you *really* think that this is what SE intended? Moreover, the SE platform has very poor tools for tracking such abuse. It is essentially under the radar. Users are being tricked into assisting this campaign without any clue of the organized campaign behind the scenes.

Comment: @BillDubuque sock puppets is an entirely different issue. If you have evidence (or just reasonable suspicion) that a user is using sock puppets for this purpose, I'd strongly suggest to send SE a mail with the details. They are the only ones that can detect this, everyone else can just guess.

Comment: @BillDubuque: what do you mean by complex dynamics? meaning that some people don't like getting their average and uninteresting answers deleted? we must accept the vote of the majority. Deleting some answers is totally ok, considering that every hundreds of new questions are asked

Comment: @T.Bongers No, it does not! The system was *explicitly redesigned* to minimize casting of *explict* delete votes deferring this to more common types of votes. This is the entire point of the system being as it is. Before this change the number of delete votes one could cast was also higher. The reason the number is so low now is *because* one can do it differently too.

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller There is no "vote of the majority" involved in these deletions, but rather the actions of *one* specific user.

Comment: @quid I seriously doubt that the system was designed in such a way to allow or encourage a use of mere downvotes (by a single user!) to force question deletion. As I see it, there is a substantial difference between having strong or frequent auto-deletion of unanswered or poorly answered questions, and seeing good answers be downvoted for no reason other than forcing deletion.

Comment: @T.Bongers: how do you know that? I also downvote some questions, in fact several, because there are so many questions which are simply of no use whatsoever, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848919/question-about-acceleration . Obviously several other people are of the same opinion.

Comment: My point was that your appeal to the "vote of the majority" was baseless. If these deletions were taking place through the normal process of $3$ experienced users casting deletion votes against specific questions, then I would have no issue with this.

Comment: @BillDubuque *if* somebody actually intends to use many sockpuppets for deleting arbitrary threads I would "recommend" they just use spam/offensive flags. // T. Bongers: I do not want to continue this comment thread too far, my point is that *downvoting to achieve deletion is part of the system* (see my comment to Hurkly re automatic dv). Whether or not this is applied in a reasonable way in this case is something else. I do not know. I cannot see the threads. I do not want to decide.

Comment: @T.Bongers: your problem is simply that my vote counts as much as yours, this is what annoys you. but I guess this is just democratic, problem Bongers?

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller That is not at all what I'm saying. The "problem Bongers," together with your avatar (and what I understand as the English translation of your username) indicate that I shouldn't spend any more time replying.

Comment: I realize that you are largely arguing about the principle of things, but the evidence brought up does not convince me. I clicked throught the five links given here as well as the five links in Bill's answer. Let me simply state that I'm not gonna shed any tears for the lost threads. Their removal is IMVHO closer to good housekeeping rather than loss of valuable content.

Comment: @Jyrki I wonder if you will feel the same when some of *your* answers to (old) questions that do not meet his quality standards are similarly deleted in this manner.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're right - a significant part of my argument is about the principle of whether a single user should be able to cause hundreds of these deletions. It also irritates me at times when the carefully written hints and answers I've put time into are removed via this process.

Comment: It remains to be seen how I react, when I'm at the receiving end. Admittedly nothing I say at this time will convince anyone. @T.Bongers the fate of hints **is** a loss. I think that hints should be used more. It might be worth a separate thread. The official SE is against hints (as are many respected posters), but I feel differently.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen whether you are at the receiving end or not, your opinion should be independent of that, I guess its not about your own interests. apart from that bongers and bill, if you really don't want to lose your work then concentrate on some few questions and write something substantial. or write a book, a paper whatever, this is much better than answering thousands of mostly boring questions.

Comment: I tend to agree, @Zlatan. I do have a number of answers I'm not proud of. Things I write out of sense of duty to keep the unanswered queue shorter in my "adopted" tags (finite-fields and coding-theory). Most of those can go without the community taking an incalculable loss. For my money the bigger deletion problem is that of the OP deleting (also unilaterally!) their question immediately I had given an answer (or sometimes a minute before). Those we can vote to undelete, so it is different. The feeling of getting used by a help-seeker doesn't wash away so easily, but them's the breaks.

Comment: FWIW: after a longish deliberation I decided to upvote this question. Initially I felt that this is yet another whining thread, but IMVHO it is a good thing that we have this discussion. It may not result in lasting changes in members behavior, but that's not necessarily the point.

Comment: Both OP and @Thisismuchhealthier. have an xkcd comic on their profile page...Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: @gnometorule: Both you and Bill have a user profile image which is not an identicon. Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: @AsafKaraglia: Shoot, busted! As you could have also seen by the great quality of my answers, I'm Bill's sock puppet. I give up already.

Comment: @gnometorule: You're a real gem, and that's the key idea.

Comment: I realize my opinion has been tainted by a poisoned well -- we assume it's just about circumventing the deletion process, but I can easily imagine a user truly thinking answers to bad questions aren't useful, and thus *should* be downvoted. *I* certainly think the majority are counterproductive, although I haven't taken the final step to cement my belief into downvoting them. And if said hypothetical user takes the time to go on a massive campaign to close and downvote deserving things, that's a *good* thing, and the only reasonable controversy would be whether the script is too generous.

Comment: ... or whether the user has overly divergent opinions about utility. While this was originally a useful abstract question, I feel the direction it has taken has dramatically changed its character.

Comment: this happened to me earlier this year before this specific user came on the scene -- downvote on my answer to zero shortly followed by automatic deletion of the question. At the time I found it a bit disappointing that someone had gamed the system, and I assumed it was a one-off.

Comment: For what it's worth, I will be using some of my votes to counter this campaign. Whenever I vote to close an (old) question, or see it appear in review, I will be looking to see if there are answers I feel are worth preserving. I encourage others who disagree with the scale and effect of the issue I've raised to do similarly.

Comment: You may be interested in the thread [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/) So far this discussion is about SO only, but Shog9 mentioned the possibility of extending some of the criteria to the rest of network.

Comment: If this isn't already asked in some way on Meta Stack Exchange, I suggest it should be asked there as it's (1) more general than math; (2) important to resolve one way or another.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. It appears to be live now, and I've edited the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: On your edit: I find it strange that you claim it would be that much effort. It seems perfectly feasible. It seems rather that neither you nor the others complaining truly care about the deleted posts, which is a main point: at the end of the day, the deleted posts are pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @quid I find it much stranger that you believe that those "complaining" think that the deleted posts are "pretty irrelevant".

Comment: @BillDubuque I did not claim that they *think* they are pretty irrelvant, I only claimed that they are pretty irrelevant to them too. It is not uncome that people think or claim something is important to them while actually judging from their actions it isn't.

Comment: @quid As one of the "others" you refer to, I can assure you that your guess is far off the mark. Perhaps you should let others speak for themselves. Meta works much better that way.

Comment: @BillDubuque the phrase you have issues with starts with "It seems" so it should be quite obvious that I am referring *my perception* of the situation at hand, which you can find flawed or irrelevant or any number of things. But I do speak for myself.

Comment: @quid If you are having difficulty understanding others think, then It is much more constructive to *ask* what they think, rather than to make wild speculations about such.

Comment: @BillDubuque There is no speculation. I referred my perception of the situation.

Comment: @quid In order to counter the actions of this *one* single user, I would have to coordinate with at least two other $10$k+ users in order to cast undelete votes on hundreds of questions; there's also a time-limited component to this, since the auto-deletions by the community user are only listed for a short time (until they are superseded by *more* deletions) in the review tools. Nor do I believe that it's reasonable to require $\ge 3$ users carrying out so many actions *just* to counter the behaviour of this one.

Comment: Why is there any need for *coordination*? As soon as there is one undelete vote, it shows up in the list of question with undelete votes. Those so short on time could just browse that list and add their votes where appropriate. (I conceed that the fact that deletions can become  almost 'invisible' relatively quickly can be annoying.) But see with the coordination you exaggerated the problem. There is a dedicated list for question with undelte votes. Moreover, it could generally be a good idea to monitor deletions. There is not just this user but also others reasons for del.

Comment: would you mind copying and paste the text of a few of those questions and answers? Otherwise it's impossible for users with <10k to form an opinion.

Comment: Why is "user61527" gone? I remember (s)he had more than 50k rep.

Comment: BillDubuque, aka @Number  about sockpuppet accounts, given your (mis)use of sockpuppet accounts, don't project what you do on most users.

Answer (score 39):

I would cast my opinion for *no*.

There is already a mechanism for interactive deletions, and it is balanced by restricting it to high-rep users and requiring multiple people to vote to delete.

The automatic deletion script, on the other hand, is a convenience feature to automate the process for posts that are among the least controversial to delete and are unlikely to ever be seen again by enough people who actually have the power to delete. In fact, I believe the origin of this feature was when moderators on one of the other SX sites started actively searching for these things, so they could cull the things that wouldn't have a chance to be "naturally" deleted.

Gaming the system is to trigger the automatic deletion to circumvent the balance on delete votes is quite inappropriate.

EDIT: This answer is meant to be a reply to the abstract question, and not a judgment on specific allegations of abuse.

Comment: There is "tools" the "being seen" is not that much of an issue. Indeed, I would assume most of the non-first delete votes come through "tools." The line of argument you present is thus somewhat week. Especially, with the old delete rules and procedure (before autodeleetion) it was pretty easy to clean up everything. This worked very well on MO before the switch.

Comment: @quid: Maybe, maybe not: my description of the origins and role of the autodelete system aren't really my point, but the first time really was "We're cleaning a lot of stuff up, it would be nice if this could be automated". The point I'm vested in with this post is about circumventing the balance on the deletion process.

Comment: Of course, part of the autodeletion is convenience, however I feel this is not all there is to it. There were also other changes, such as stricter limitation of the number of manual delete votes available. A point of these changes was IMO to better integerate deletion with more usual types of voting (up/down and open/close) and to rather avoid manual deletion. Recall that until some time ago an *automatic dv* was cast as a consequence of certain types of closure with the *explict intent* to push such question towards deletion via a dv. (This was taken back for other reasons.)

Comment: Thus dv with a view towards something getting deleted was *even built into the system.* I thus cannot understand you talking about gaming the system and circumventing the balance. The procedure in my perception is perfectly in line with "the system."  If you do not like the design or the behavior this is one thing (I do not consider it as that good an idea either.) But to claim somebody is gaming the system seems unfair.

Comment: @quid I *strongly* disagree. This massive deletion campaign is sneakily exploiting a big loophole in the design of the SE platform. Most users voting to close these questions have no idea that good answers will be deleted, or that many good answers were downvoted multiple times for the sole purpose of deleting the entire thread. In fact most reviewers do not even see the answers when they vote to close since the review queue does not display them. Even if they did, they might be misled to believe that the answers were not helpful, due to them being downvoted to $0$ in order to trigger deletion

Comment: @BillDubuque if you believe that there is some exploit you should signal it to the moderators or SE staff. Also, if they exist it should be easy to document the existence of "many good answers [that] were downvoted **multiple** times for the sole purpose of deleting the entire thread" (my emph). *If* somebody does this using more than one account I would consider it as highly problematic. [While I typed this comment I noticed that some example were added, *I* cannot check how many have *multiple* dv; could such information be added, it seems crucial to evaluate the situation.]

Comment: @quid's last point is IMHO crucial. If I understood it correctly the community can prevent these unilateral closures by giving TWO upvotes to the most deserving answer. In more esoteric tags finding those two upvotes may be taxing, but the listed questions were mostly at freshman level if not high school. IOW the community has the tools to combat this. Upvote!

Comment: @Jyrki That's what I recommend in my answer. If you vote to close a question and it has good answers all having low score, then upvoting at least one of the answers to score $3$ will probably prevent the thread from being deleted. Whether or not score $3$ is high enough or not depends on how many user accounts are collaborating in this massive deletion campaign.

Comment: @Bill: Arguably, there is no such thing as a good answer to a question that *should* be closed (short proof: there isn't a meaningful measure of *intrinsic* goodness of an answer. Goodness is only meaningful relative to its role as an answer to the question). I feel your argument strongly relies on your supposition that the question shouldn't be closed in the first place.

Comment: @Hurkyl Most definitely *arguably*. But let's argue that elsewhere, since that would push this thread very far off-topic.

Comment: You saw [the numbers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/14996/), Hurkyl: over a 12-month period, the 10K users deleted 218 questions in total, 0.6 questions per day. Compared to the amount of garbage pouring it, this is nothing short of pathetic. 10K users collectively failed to protect the site from low-quality content, substituting endless pondering on meta for taking action on main. Years into the debate, you are still waiting for your belief to "cement" into doing something. *Whether ’tis nobler in the mind to suffer...*

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Going on a one-person mission to cleanse the site of questions you don't like is not, in my very humble opinion, an appropriate response to the state of the website. I think the general consensus (at least indicated by vote counts *here*) is that your actions are causing a serious loss of good content; if you could convince the community your actions are proper, then that would be a different situation entirely. Keep in mind that I say this as one of the *most* prolific close-voters on the site.

Comment: @T.: There was a bait and switch that really invalidates any inferences one might make about vote counts on question as relating to the general consensus about the desirability of retaining the content of the targeted question threads.

Comment: @Hurkyl I apologize for the radical change to the question after it was asked; I felt it was an important issue to bring to light, and after seeing the answer of the person who motivated the question, I felt that I should make it much more specific. I've edited the original post to clarify this - I certainly didn't intend to have a bait-and-switch here. (Also, the majority of the votes cast on any of these answers came after the edit to the original post).

Comment: @T.Bongers You are entitled to *your* opinion. Other users' votes reflect *their* opinion. My votes reflect *my* opinion. It's that simple.

Comment: When your opinion becomes a crusade affecting hundreds of questions and answers, then it's a bit more than an opinion. I don't necessarily disagree with your ideals here, but rather the implementation.

Comment: Oops.  I voted down instead of up, and now my vote is locked in.  This is a *very* important issue, and I certainly agree with this post.

Answer (score 34):

There are so many approaches and reasons to upvoting and downvoting here (=Math.SE, not Meta) that it is IMHO largely pointless to attempt to codify them. A discussion is, of course, ok, if for no other purpose than to vent one's frustration. To simplify matters somewhat let me attempt to break them into three categories. It would be a miracle, if even a majority agreed with my grouping :-)

## **Downvotes - Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo**

### *1. The Good downvotes*

These are the downvotes cast at worthless questions and erroneous answers. Some prefer comments explaining the errors in answers to downvotes, some revert a comment to a downvote as a last measure if the poster of erroneous material does not react. These will hardly ever cause an uproar in Meta. I guess the level of disagreement is tolerable to all and sundry. Downvoting plagiarized answers might fall into this category, but the burden of proof is a problem.

### *2. The Bad downvotes*

This is the other end of the spectrum. The downvotes that are nearly universally condemned: Revenge downvotes, serial downvotes, downvotes following a disagreement in Meta or other unpleasant exchange. Downvoting competing answers for the sake of bringing ones own up. A common feature is that the target of the downvote is *the poster* as opposed to *the post*. (This doesn't fit the last item in the list, but I include that among the Bad motives anyway.) Sure, the caster of such a downvote can allude himself to having other motives that guide the selection of the post being downvoted, but only manages to deceive himself (if that). If you are hit with one these, the advice is to flag it. Alternatively you can just decide that 1) somebody was having a bad day, 2) take one for the team, 3) and move on.

### *3. The Ugly downvotes*

Everything else in between. Largely downvotes targeted at *a behavior* of a poster as opposed to the poster themselves. Motives like the practice of: asking a PSQ, answering a PSQ, giving a copy/pastable answer to a HW, giving hints only, posting nearly duplicate answers to the same question, posting duplicate answers to different questions or other things that can be viewed as *rep farming*. Answering a question while other member(s) try to engage the asker with hints/suggestions/questions about context (the last item is debatably bad). Whatever irritates you — the list goes on (and grows as we invent new peeves).

It is easy to justify ugly downvotes to yourself. After all, you seek to improve the quality of the site as a whole. Or at least pull it in the direction that you yourself
prefer. Nothing much wrong with that as the weight of the sum of voters is then what matters, right?

An easy justification for Ugly downvotes is that up/downvoting is *the only tool we are given* to steer the development of the forum. Of course, a more enlightened thing might be to write a comment explaining the reason of the annoyance. If that doesn't work, then...

A big con (as pointed out to me by others in related threads) of Ugly downvotes is that they are often difficult to distinguish from downvotes targeting a person. If the downvoter is targeting a behavioral pattern, it is natural to take the history of the "miscreant" into account. After all it is common sense to simply point out to a newbie their faux pas. But after basing such downvotes to a history of the user are you then not targeting the user as opposed to their behavior?

### *Why do we react differently?*

Come on! Silly of me to ask! We are people! Some may have come to this place from an environment, where "only Good downvotes" was the norm (MO?), and think of everything else as an insult to the professional standards. Some may have come from an environment where like/dislike votes are cast freely, and let them slide. Some may have had next to zero social media history when joining in, and their behavior is based on the learning curve of the chaotic response they encounter here.

### *Did I have a point?*

I react negatively to posts that I perceive to be under the umbrella of *my ugly downvotes are defensible, but their ugly downvotes are an abomination*. Many of them smack of whining, but I guess it is good to let the poison come out.

I'm afraid I have cast a number of Ugly downvotes myself. I don't feel particularly proud of any of them, and I am trying to learn away from them. I feel the pain and frustration of the fallen brothers, when they try to salvage a decent math site from becoming a homework factory. You have my sympathy, but there should be a better way.

What to do when having a bad day and feeling like littering downvotes left and right? I dunno. Cast one, and simmer in the guilt until the feeling passes away? Whine in a suitable Meta-thread?

I have been teetering at the edge of the abyss of a downvoting spree. I took the "whine on Meta"-route. With the fortunate result that Asaf felt like picking my reasoning apart. He enjoys messing with me occasionally — and is welcome to do so :-). The pain and shame of having my argument punctured full of holes kept me from falling to the dark side on those occasions.

I don't know if I really had a point.

> R.I.P Ennio Morricone

Comment: [No comment.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWo__6Xn6Qs) :-) [Also, have I really done that? It fits my profile, so I won't deny anything this time.]

Comment: It's rare for an answer this long to be so entertaining that I actually read through to the end of it. Not saying I agree with it, just that it was a pleasure to read.

Comment: Interesting answer. Since you mention MO, it is common practice of some (not me so much) to dv *reasonable* answers to question they consider off-topic. This is by and large accepted behavior. And of course MO also has ad hominem voting and other bad things.

Comment: @Asaf: Our little exchanges on Meta have had the described affect. Twice IIRC. It probably was not your main objective, but the resulting Gibbs slap had such an effect on me anyway :-) A pause causing me to reconsider is all that was needed.

Comment: @quid I confess that I cannot make any sense of your comparison to MO (MathOverflow). To me it makes as little sense as comparing the acceptance policies for articles submitted to the journals  *Amer. Math. Monthly* vs. *Annals of Math*. $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I am not *comparing* anything. I described the situation on MO as I see it. The reason I considered this as *relevant* is that in the post you can read: "Some may have come to this place from an environment, where "only Good downvotes" was the norm (MO?)" That is, the question how the situation is on MO was raised quite explicitly. Therefore, I explained the situation on MO as I see it, to answer this question.

Comment: @quid My remark applies to that as well. MO has little to nothing to do with this site. *General-level* math forums always have been, and always will be, very unique beasts, facing very unique challenges.

Comment: @BillDubuque the post does not compare the two sites either; certainly it does not propose to adopt the practice of MO or even only to take the practice on MO as a guide. To the contrary, it speculates that the policy on MO might/should be very different from the one described and somehow promoted in this post for this site. Incidentally, and somewhat ironically, what you seem to want for this site is what J.L. speculated to be the case on MO.

Comment: Sorry to have created some confusion. During an earlier related discussion some people expressed as a strong opinion that mathematical errors are the only acceptable reason for downvotes.  I was, indeed, speculating here that may be their different background (a long history at MO ?) would explain their different expectations about how people should downvote.

Comment: I don't believe in downvoting at all, but I don't have any strong objection to Good downvotes by others. However, I am frankly appalled that downvoting readable, mathematically correct answers that don't violate a request for hints only is not in your Bad list, recognized as the vandalism that it in fact is. (And I have no interest whatsoever in participating in NO.)

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the comment. I guess all the ugly and the bad downvotes are about mathematically correct posts (when dealing with answers). Can't say I'm surprised to hear that you don't see any shades of grey, or more facetiously, bad/ugly among such votes. I'm afraid that such differences of opinion are at the heart of much acrimony here. Others also pointed out that the comparison to MO was misguided. I was simply speculating that members' different history with social media and/or math forums might explain the differences in their expectations as to what a downvote means.

Comment: @Jyrki: Indeed, I’m very much with the OP on this issue. (I take it from evidence in the comments that it was T.Bongers; I’m pleasantly surprised, given his enthusiasm for closing questions, and — despite that enthusiasm! — I’m sorry to see him go, since he wrote excellent answers. I have to admit, though, that I sympathize, and if I end up crossing paths very often with the specific user in question, I may disappear again sooner rather than later.)

Comment: I'm afraid the development of the site has made Ugly downvotes a norm. Too many users ignore the compromise rules on homework and duplicates.

Answer (score 17):

Here is some important context. There is, apparently, a *massive* campaign orchestrated by one user to delete all questions (*and their answers!*) if the question does not meet his standards of quality. This campaign appears to target not only recent questions, but *every* question, including questions many years old. As best as I can infer, this campaign has been in the works [for many months](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13756/242) (possibly much longer), but has only recently ramped up to full steam. Now, with many thousands of (multiple) downvotes cast on answers, entire threads of questions (and all answers) can be deleted *en masse* by simply pushing the question into the close review queue to get it closed, which will later trigger an *irreversible* automatic deletion of the entire thread by the Community bot.

Below is a sample of various helpful answers that were deleted yesterday (from the hundreds that are already deleted or soon scheduled to be). Note that it is the same  user who first voted to close, pushing the question into the close queue, to help trigger the automatic deletion.

$\quad$ [thread1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701376/show-that-the-relation-in-set-of-real-number-is-an-equivalence) $\   $
[thread2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784820/statisticsprobality-example-2) $\   $
[thread3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811692/misunderstanding-easy-inequality-problem) $\   $
[thread4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792953/a-cylindrical-container-problem) $\   $
[thread5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768999/find-the-area-of-the-region-integral-application)

If this campaign continues unchecked, then a significant percentage of site content will be deleted, *irreversibly*, since normal users cannot vote to undelete content deleted by a moderator such as the Community user. This will cause the deletion of *many* fine answers  (esp. those composed at a time when majority views on questions standards differed greatly from current majority views).

It is important that all users who vote on such matters be aware of how their votes may help to further this campaign. I suspect that most users who have been active in the closure review queue did not realize that their votes would later lead to irreversible deletions of many good answers. Please give such matters very careful consideration the next time you review a question for closure. If it has good answers then upvote the answers to help prevent the entire thread from being deleted by the Community bot (which requires all answers to have score $\le 0).$ It seems that there are only a few users and/or sockpuppets involved in downvoting the answers, so if the answers are upvoted high enough then that will prevent the campaign from downvoting the answers to $0$, so it will prevent the thread from being automatically deleted by the Community bot.

Finally, I propose that we petition SE for the capability to undelete content that was deleted by the Community bot. As is clear from the above, there is much potential for abuse, without any way for normal users to reverse such. Though diamond mods can reverse such deletions, they are already overworked. Moreover, decisions on important matters such as these should involve as many experienced community members as is possible, so that we can leverage the combined wisdom of the community in the hope of making the best decisions possible for our very diverse community.

Comment: Although I don't agree with the totality of this answer, there's a really good point here - deletion is a privilege that's restricted to very few users for some very good reasons. Question closures (whether they are viewed as appropriate or not) have to be preceded by the consent of $5$ distinct users, whereas this method of forcing deletion can be carried out by $1$. I almost never vote to close a question with the ultimate goal of seeing it deleted, except in the obvious cases.

Comment: @T.Bongers What do disagree with?

Comment: Apparently I had misread something, so never mind on the disagreement. So far, though, I don't really see any evidence of sock-puppeting or multiple voting (aside from the serial voting that was resolved a month ago).

Comment: @T.Bongers Evidence for such was mentioned in the [prior thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13756/242), but the discussion was deleted by an SE mod. In any case, what matters more is not if the massive deletion compaign is led by one or a few users but, rather, that this compaign may cause the deletion of much valuable content from the site, which may alienate many users. It is important that the community be *explicitly* aware of this campaign, since it will have a significant global effect on the site.

Comment: @Bill: Your concern is valid in that there are many ok questions and/or answers that only have zero-score answers or anyway $\le+1$ answers. And these are exactly the posts that are under threat here. I have recently started an upvoting campaign of material that I like to see here. Why don't you join in and start upvoting answers as well? Practice what you preach and all that. Edit: For the record, this is not to be read as me having doubts about the example deletions being a good thing. No tears for their loss from me.

Comment: I do find it rather curious that a user so prolific in *answering* questions, and in encouraging others to upvote good content, has cast a mere $889$ votes in a $4$-year tenure; and barely two-fifths of these are upvotes.

Comment: @T.Bongers If I spend more time reading and (carefully) evaluating answers then I will have much less time to compose answers. But the latter is where I firmly believe that I can add the most value to the site. There are front-page users who have cast far fewer votes than I in a few years, e.g. under 200. But this is not the place to discuss such.

Comment: @Bill: I think that they burnt Andre the Giant's body. Sitting on a pile of ash is not that impressive.

Comment: People who want to help stoping the campaign can just look at the profile of the user who is doing it, click activities, click reviews, find all posts where he has casted a [closevote](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/this-is-much-healthier?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and then take measures to counteract it (simple downvotes are not trackable though). I am really surprised that such a behavior is not worth of earning an enforced "time out" for the user who seems to be on some kind of crazy literally destructive crusade ...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have, indeed, seen much further by standing on the shoulders of giants. I guarantee you that cannot be achieved by sitting on one's ash!

Comment: @BillDubuque: I would like to thank you for your consistent and energetic defense of values, and for showing that answers to technically "simple" questions can shed light on ideas.

Comment: @Bill: Fine, standing on a pile of ashes. And let me just point to you that far is a relative term. For an ant, from one end of my desk to the other is "far". For me, it's just stretching both my arms. If you compare yourself to a creature small of size, like the one which can stand on the shoulders of giants to begin with, one has to question your definition of "far" and "further".

Comment: @Dilaton now *this* would actually be gaming the system, as this information is not public so that some user can be stalked and obstructed. (But it would not really work so well anyway.)

Comment: @Dilaton That's possible only when this user uses the normal thread-closing system.  T. Bongers is specifically asking about an exploit of the automated deletion system: "In particular, there are closed questions with 1-point answers - when the answer(s) are downvoted to 0, they are then eligible for automatic deletion, which can only be undone by the moderators."  Since it's not possible to see someone's downvotes, it's not possible to systematically oppose this behavior, even if that were desirable.

Comment: -1, since this is making the issue about "I don't think these questions should be deleted" rather than about the means by which are getting deleted.

Comment: As an aside, if I was convinced people were upvoting an answer not  because they think it is a useful answer but instead to try and ward off automatic deletion, I would *strongly* consider offering a downvote to counteract it.

Comment: @Hurkyl -1. The offenders are the people who abuse the deletion script (together with close and downvotes) to undermine the deletion privilege, and get rid of content without humans having the possibility to supervise what they are doing. It is those people who are behaving as bad guys so the good guys have to oppose the evil intentions of the previously mentioned bad guys. To me it seems, you have the causality of the issue upside down. The people who try to prevent bad things from happening are good by definition. And in turn people opposing the good guys are bad guys by definition too ...

Comment: @Hurkyl good point re the counteract. I will reiterate my first comment on OP that  a single upvote for an answer is sometimes cast just to prevent repeated bumping of the question later not so much for the intrinsic merits of the answer, which arguably can serve as additional justification for the dv's and practice we are discussing.

Comment: @Hurkyl Please, once again, do not quote me as saying something that I never said. Oh for the day when meta arguments will clean, fair and constructive.

Comment: @Bill: That would be the day when the meta is effectively run by a single user (or less), with power to suspend and delete all opposition. That is probably the day when this site will meet its end.

Comment: Contrary to what is said in this answer, there has never been any evidence that the user in question employed sockpuppets. The proposed sockpuppet candidates Bill gave on the thread he linked were accounts where even unregistered users could easily verify that they are not sockpuppets (I tried it out). In particular, creation and last-activity dates made it impossible for them to be interacting at some time. I'm shocked that a former moderator didn't show this minimal due diligence before starting public accusations.

Comment: @Michael First, no one said what you claim they did. Second, this has little to do with the primary issue(s) of this thread. Third, one of accounts involved has now listed *some* of their many prior accounts, e.g. see the [crowd-sourced biography](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/this-is-much-healthier) in their profile.

Comment: @Michael Fourth, anyone with intimate knowledge of the SE platform could easily stay under the radar of the limited tools available to diamond mods. In fact they could easily stay under the radar of those with access to the database. It would be impossible to detect collusion were it organized by a savvy enough user. Now let's get back on topic, eh?

Comment: @BillDubuque You considered the stuff you posted as evidence for sockpuppeteering. It is not.

Comment: @Michael Those are your words, not mine.  In any case, if you want to learn more about this (tangential) topic, I strongly advise that you start with a database dump of the MSE site, and then perform some *serious* statistical analyses (using much more powerful tools than the very-limited mickey-mouse tools SE provides to diamond mods). I guarantee that you will be greatly surprised by the results (and not only regarding this matter).

Comment: @Bill Regardless of the (seemingly dubious) claims of voting fraud, I must say that I'm becoming a bit offended at the sheer flippancy displayed by the user in question, in both answers and the autobiography.

Comment: @T.Bongers In this thread, I think it is best to forget about tangential topic of the possibility that rules may have been violated in this long-running campaign. Rather, it is best to focus on the primary issues: is it appropriate to downvote (good) answers for the purpose of deleting questions that one deems to be "low quality", and should the community have the power to reverse these single-handed decisions?

Comment: @BillDubuque sorry to engage you in yet another comment conversation but re "Those are your words, not mine." You said (4th comment here) "Evidence for such was mentioned in the prior thread, but the discussion was deleted by an SE mod." where such was "sock-puppeting or multiple voting." Who mentioned this evidence other than you or is the issue that 'or multiple voting' was dropped? Or what precisley is not your words here? [Though then it is not quite clear what multiple voting should be without a sock; I mean most things get multiple votes and it would be nonissue usually.]

Comment: @T.Bongers No offence was meant. But let me play Bill's advocate for a moment. No downvote is needed to trigger deletion of answers to a closed question if the answers have zero score to begin with. This means that you, being such a prolific close-voter, must have triggered lots of irreversible answer deletions (including answers posted between your VTC and the 5th one, answers you haven't even seen). Do you seriously believe that score of 1 = "good content", while score of 0 = "not good"? If not, how do you justify  causing *serious loss of good content*?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. You're quite right - I'm sure I've triggered some of these deletions, which I view as an unfortunate (inasmuch as they cannot be undeleted by non-mods) side effect. But I see several key differences: My close votes are never unilateral, but are rather done in coordination with four other users. Nor do I ever downvote good mathematical answers (which I generally view as a misuse of downvoting). Furthermore, my close votes are not part of an apparent crusade - the volume is generally limited to what I see in the queues, and what I come across with in the new queue...

Comment: So in summary, my key complaints are the volume, the (IMHO) misuse of downvotes, the irreversible deletions that come from this process, and the complete lack of oversight or consensus with other users that these votes involve. The last two are the most important to me.

Comment: As for me, I think [the volume of deletions is too low](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question#comment57350_15131), I reject the strict [correctness-based approach to voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10479/), support [proposals for better oversight](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/two-feature-requests-regarding-deleted-questions#comment57566_15156) and leave the irreversibility issue for SE team to figure out. Have a good weekend, @T.Bongers.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Very well; your approach is at least self-consistent. I suppose that I will simply leave it at that; enjoy the weekend.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.  Hello there.  I've just learned of your campaign via this answer.  If I understand how your campaign works correctly, and perhaps I don't, it would seem that your standards differ significantly from the community's standards as a whole.  Consequently I ask, what are your standards for trying to get a question deleted?

Comment: And @Numbers, better known as BillDubuque, it is imperative that users carefully question your motives and your campaign to allow PSQ's that you are so eager to answer (and earn rep from).

Answer (score 13):

I haven't read everything written in the other answers/comments/linked comments/questions in question, but here are a few of my thoughts.

1) First, I am one of those people who will vote to close a question that shows no effort. I know that this isn't the topic under discussion here, but since the questions linked to above were closed because of lack of context, it might be relevant.

2) I think it is unethical to try to game the system in anyway.

3) If you see a question that you believe should be closed, then just vote to close it. I have, myself, several times initiated the closure of a number of questions within a limited timespan. But I didn't do so because I was trying to game the system in anyway. I don't know that it is fair to single out the one user mentioned above. I am against PSQs and so when I see one I often vote to close (I don't always do this). I don't do it because I secretly want the question to be deleted. I vote to close/put on hold and then I hope that the OP will edit the context and add context. If the OP doesn't want to do this, then I am fine with the question ultimately being deleted.

4) I think that it should always be possible to vote to undelete a deleted question question.

5) I believe that any downvote should be accompanied by a comment explaining why the downvote was given. The only exception is when the answer is spam or other obvious inappropriate content.

6) I (for the most) only downvote answers if I believe that they are mathematically wrong (in which case I leave a comment and wait with the downvote until the poster has had time to edit). Besides that, I might downvote a question that I believe fails to address the OP's actual question. Again, I don't think about what consequences the downvote has in terms of future deletions.

7) Maybe "some of this" can be solved if people would upvote more?

Comment: The problem with posting many opinions as above is that it makes the votes to your answer completely meaningless. Which points do the votes target? I disagree with some of your points, and I agree with others. Probably the same is true for many users. How do you expect them to vote? $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque up if one agrees with the general sentiment and down if one disagrees with the general sentiment (typically explaining what the diagreement is). If one is in the middle one simply does not vote at all.

Comment: @quid But that is of little value in helping to judge community opinion on the multiple *specific* points, since one cannot know which points the votes target (or not).

Comment: @BillDubuque do you mean to propose Thomas posts 7 answers?

Comment: Thomas, the seventh point [was discussed here before](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often).

Comment: @quid I don't recall ever proposing any remedy for that defect in the SE platform. But it will be remedied in some platforms in the works.

Comment: @BillDubuque oh, so your first comment was just a bit of general complaning about the platform. Sorry, I thought you had some specific concern and/or advice  regarding the format of the current answer.

Comment: @Quid Be serious. The point of my first comment is clear. If you wish for the votes on a meta answer to be meaningful then be sure that they target a *unique* point (or points where there is unlikely to be any disagreement). I often emphasize this because it helps meta to work more efficiently (and helps to avoid abuses - which is not an issue here).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I am sorry for the many points in my "answer" above. It seemed like the OP was "asking" two questions, so to express my opinion best, I needed more than one point. Also, it seems that the discussion is related to other topics that, again, I felt needed to be tied into the discussion. May I ask exactly what points you (dis)agree with?

Comment: @Thomas No need to apologize. I was simply relaying some advice that I thought would prove helpful. I don't think it would be wise to engage *here* in a discussion of the points on which I disagree, since they are tangential to the topic at hand, so doing so would only serve to further derail this thread (a big problem on meta).  The more "related" topics you offer opinions on, the more chance you have of alienating potential voters (as you did I).

Comment: @BillDubuque  I think it is a lot better when people take the time to develop a nuanced position, as opposed to shooting off some sound bite in the hope to gather a lot of votes. Votes to be meaningful on meta is not a major concern (to me). They are not even that meaningful on main. Why care about them that much on meta. Further to the your critique of this post, the structure of the post makes voicing partial agreement or disagreement relatively easy. In contrast to your post, for example, that also is not that much making a unique point. (Partially witnessed by the very first comment.)

Comment: In sum, it is difficult to see something *constructive* in your first comment. It is some generic criticism that could be made on every other meta post at least, including yours in this very thread. Perhaps I should repost it? :-)

Comment: @quid You're comparing apples vs. oranges. My post was not meant to measure community opinion on some issue. Rather, it was meant to inform the community of some important context. Now, isn't it about time to stop beating this dead horse, so that more important issues can be discussed?

Comment: @BillDubuque So what? OP here meant to share a few of their thoughts. I am not sure why here voting in your sense must make sense, and in your case it is a nonissue. You did not only inform about some context. You also proposed a petition. SO does a vote mean one dis/agrees with the petition or one consider the context as not/useful or as not/accurate. Is it clear? Is this the same? Why is it irrelevant their? (I know this is off-topic here, so I will try to stop it here.)

Comment: PSQ??? what is that?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Meta shorthand for "Problem Statement Question", a question that consists of nothing else but a [usually copy-pasted] homework assignment plus possibly something along the lines of "NEED HALPZ URGENT!!1-eleven". If it contains so much as "I tried integrating by parts but it didn't get better", it is no longer a PSQ.

Answer (score -18):

You really miss that "equation of tangent line" answer, don't you? But that's what I do,  among [other things](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846563/using-normal-families-to-bound-a-complex-integral#comment1748068_847499).

I think it's  appropriate. Others may disagree and that's okay with me.  Heracles got his [$5$th labor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labours_of_Hercules#Fifth_Labour:_Augean_stables) discounted because his method was considered inappropriate. There may be some parallel here.

---

*Added*: The "air of negativity" comment reminded me of the infamous "Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late" thread (>1000 upvotes, 6 close-reopen cycles, 54 answers). The [top-voted answer by Mysticial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/) is worth reading, especially for users who keep insisting that Math.SE is oh-so-very-different from other large SE sites.

Comment: I didn't link to that answer (although it was the most recent inspiration for this question) because I wanted my question to be about general mores, not about my particular posts; and although I greatly appreciate your high-quality answer to my recent question, I completely fail to see its relevance to the question I've posed here. I was aware that this is one of the actions you regularly carry out, but I didn't name you in the original post - again, I'm asking about community opinion, not about the appropriateness of actions taken by individual users on specific questions.

Comment: @T.B, "community opinion" is the sum of the opinions of individual community members (perhaps with some weighting), and Dr. Healthier is giving her opinion that the practice you object to is appropriate. As I write this, Healthier's opinion has 3 downvotes and no upvotes, so maybe you are beginning to get some idea of community opinion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, and my comment was a bit poorly worded. I am interested in the justification that Healthier would provide, but didn't see any of that here - rather, the link to a comment of appreciation that I left is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @T.Bongers There was no explanation in the [the prior thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13756/242) for the reasons behind this campaign, which includes $2575$ downvotes and $0$ upvotes cast in the $59$ days since this account was created. Hence, probably, there will be no explanation here too. This is certainly not "much healthier". It is the most nonconstructive activity that I've seen since the inception of the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque Indeed, and it appears that I am (once again) the target of coordinated downvoting, including against the question Healthier has linked to.

Comment: Honestly, I find the way in which you use the site to be extremely harmful. Although you do contribute good answers, you have never once taken a positive voting action, but rather seem to spend the vast majority of your time working to *remove* content. There's a serious difference between voting to close an old low-quality question, and deleting all the (good and bad) answers that go with it. That's why deletion votes are one of the very last privileges granted based on reputation. Your *thousands* of downvotes, many of which are independent of quality, create an air of negativity here.

Comment: as a member of the lower (working) class I appreciate your work, keep going and clean this up! may the force be with you

Comment: @T.Bongers Another point worth noting: most of the [recent answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/this-is-much-healthier?tab=answers) given by this user are to questions missing context, motivation, etc. exactly the types of questions that he seems to be deleting. Apparently his quality standards do not apply to questions that contain his own answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque so vote to close them :-)

Comment: @quid I very rarely vote to close, and not for those reasons.

Comment: I agree with you that there is a *tremendous* amount of junk on the site, and truly terrible questions that should be closed. The issues of camps 2 and 3 have led to a serious decline in site quality recently. But going on a one-person crusade to fix this, via (what I consider to be) improper and misleading downvotes, is not the correct response. You should make an effort to build a community consensus about this issue, instead of carrying this out unilaterally and with absolutely zero review by other users.

Comment: @T.Bongers The correct way to fix this is to design much better filtering tools, so that users see only the type of questions that they like. This is not rocket science. It could easily be implemented.

Comment: @Bill, maybe so, but in the meantime...?

Comment: @Bill It seems this user answers questions without much context if they add in a useful way to the knowledge repository of MSE. That is not my standard, which is more restrictive, but I certainly see a difference to the downvoted questions and answers that were given as examples.

Comment: @Michael Which is, no doubt the same reason motivating many users who answer such questions. It should be up to the *community* to decide the value of such answers - not one user.

Comment: @BillDubuque My comment was only meant to adress the issue whether the user in question applies the same standard used for downvoting to the questions they choose to answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque This the community against one user rhetoric while sort of popular here really does not hold water. The community decides by having assigned as status to the question one that results in deletion. That this mainly happened by non-action does not alter this fact. If you consider the criteria for autdeletion as flawed file a feature request.

Comment: @quid Nonsense. Any user can look at the many examples given here and see for themselves precisely what is being orchestrated behind the scenes in a very covert manner. To me, this is *by far* the most unethical behavior that I have ever seen on the site (which includes the time when I was a moderator, which opens one eyes to all sorts of abuses). It is also, by far, the most *damaging*, with even greater potential for such if it is not stopped.

Comment: @BillDubuque "Any user can look at the many examples given here[..]" How can I do this? You do realize the examples are *deleted.* But then "[...] the evidence brought up does not convince me. I clicked throught the five links given here as well as the five links in Bill's answer. Let me simply state that I'm not gonna shed any tears for the lost threads. Their removal is IMVHO closer to good housekeeping rather than loss of valuable content. –  Jyrki Lahtonen" is good enough for me not to worry.

Comment: @quid Thanks for confirming that you have not even bothered to read important context. Now I understand why most of your comments do not seem to pertain to the matters at hand. If you read further you'll find that Jyrki elaborated on the remark, expressing later doubts. In any case, I urge everyone to make your own decision on such matters, by browsing the many deleted useful answers, now in the hundreds - soon to be thousands.

Comment: @BillDubuque What *precisely* are you referring to when you say that J.L. elaborated on the remark in the sense you claim? [It can't be just that he said it is good to have the discussion.] Also, you keep saying everyone should browse the deleted question. To repeat a question just ask: How can I do this? Also, when will you provide the many examples of multiple downvotes you claimed to exist and that I asked about?

Comment: @quid Alas, I see now that you don't have enough rep to browse the deleted questions (10K tools). This is another problem with this campaign (and the design of the SE platform). Users can be tricked into triggering a supermod Community deletion and there is no way for them to even see that this happened, because it requires very high rep to see these things. This is very poor system design. There should be checks and balances at all levels, so that users at each level can see the effects of their actions. The current design violates fundamental design principles, enabling such abuses/attacks.

Comment: @BillDubuque Given that I mentioned *explicitly* in an earlier comment that even notified you (albeit in a part not directed at you) that "I cannot see the threads" I am wondering which one of us two does not pay attention. :-)

Comment: @quid That was not clear from what you wrote prior, esp. since I thought you had 10k+ here, but it is not here, but instead MO where you are 10k+. That's the source of the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Bill, if you want less things deleted, vote more. This is just one user. If he can delete with a single downvote, this means that the answers could not have score higher than $1$. If at least two people would vote, then at least two people are required for an automatic deletion to occur (not to mention five for the closure). If you are going to complain that you better spend your time writing answers than reading and voting other people's answers, then perhaps you should consider the case that most of what gets deleted is not something you consider worth voting, and thus saving.

Comment: Bill, Michael: There isn't a point in discussing whether I apply the same standards to my posts as to the posts of others. Nobody is an impartial judge of things they are invested in. This is why mathematicians don't referee their own papers. If anyone feels I posted something I shouldn't have, they are *very* welcome to downvote, VTC, and/or vote to delete. In extreme cases, maybe even leave a comment -- though I much prefer not to have unnecessary pings in my inbox.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. It seems to me that you don't trust others to do their work. If you deem some question must be closed, you can do so, and if you want it deleted, you can vote to delete it. But this is a community forum, so it is logical that people frown upon gaming the system to achieve unilateral deletions and whatnot. It seems unfair, too, that people which are giving some of their time to post useful solutions (cf. the questions deleted by community) get their posts downvoted (when the downvote is clearly not called for, except to delete the post) and subsequently deleted. Many (...)

Comment: (...) of my *answers* are also useful to me, since they record a proof of a fact I might sooner or later forget, or the OP will. I find it much unhealthy to unilaterally delete posts, since you're deleting information (no matter how basic or trivial) that *other* people *do* find useful.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff FWIW, I [support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262717/) greater access to one's deleted content. I do not consider posting routine solutions to routine exercises a useful activity, and my votes reflect that.

Comment: @This Please keep in mind that this site is meant for math questions at *all* levels. What you consider a routine answer may be quite nonroutine to a beginner. To some experts, probably almost all of the answers here in their field are routine, but they don't downvote and close to trigger their deletion. If you seek a site restricted by level, then consider instead MathOverflow.

Comment: @BillDubuque If you seek a site for doing others' homework, then consider instead Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: @This in NOT much healthier. Is that the best you could do for a strawman? So much for hoping that you might engage in a *constructive* discussion.