# Closed questions fully answered into the comments

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, closed-questions

I don't think it is appropriate to answer closed questions into the comments as it happens [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015052/prove-x3-2-is-maximal-ideal-of-bbb-qx). Can (or should) we do something with such things?

Comment: It is certainly discouraged to use comments in that way, particularly if the goal is to give an answer to a question that is on hold or closed. But, if someone does this only very occasionally, there's not much that can be done. If they do it routinely, I hope a moderator will contact them privately to ask them to stop.

Comment: It's a natural reaction against the crowd who go around closing questions by new users before the user has had any opportunity to improve the presentation a question. I'm not saying it's a good thing, just that I'm surprised it didn't happen months ago.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe there are some users very eager to close ill formulated questions and/or without showing any effort, but my experience shows that even so if the OP came back and adds few words to his question this is usually reopened.

Comment: [It's a matter of principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011349/moment-generating-function-and-likelihood#comment2067577_1011349) for the user doing that: "Don't mind the downvotes and the closers. It means nothing but a fault of character of those how did it."

Comment: I don't see a case for moderator involvement. Two of the questions have been deleted by now; others are on their way. The user can spend their time posting short-lived comments until they get tired of it.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii As far as I can see that questions were deleted by mods, right? At least this is the way I understand "This question was removed from Mathematics Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation".

Comment: No, both were deleted by votes of 10K users. The statement "reasons of moderation" is used for all deletions that are not by the author of the post.

Comment: I suspect, 26857, that a lot of OPs, especially the ones for whom the experience comes the very first time they show up here, are put off by having their question shut down, and leave the site in horror, never to return; whereas, with a bit of helpful commenting, they might become regular and valued contributors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or maybe return to their homework with a little more determination.

Comment: Or maybe just give up on Mathematics altogether, and go do something else. There is no reason why we can't be a little more friendly, a little more welcoming, to new users. We have, I think, more to gain than to lose.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: the challenge, of course, is that if user A tries to be friendly by leaving detailed and polite comments on how to improve the question, but doesn't vote to close it, user B may come in and write an answer before the OP gets around to editing the question; in a way user B is impolitely undercutting user A's friendly comments. There seems to be no way for user A to prevent this without also voting to close. In the past, even some frequent users who commented on meta asking for more friendliness wouldn't agree not to write early answers to poorly composed questions!

Comment: What's to gain? More new users who know that if they post their homework questions here, someone will answer it no matter what. What's to lose? A website where interesting questions with lasting value are not drowned in a sea of calc 2 and linear algebra homework. Just last month, a user wrote on meta "I really don't care if the question is closed and deleted, since I got the answer". And how can I blame them?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You are looking to "What's to lose" in the wrong way. The website already has a tag for homework questions. The 'drowning' can disappear for you if you use the built-in potential of the website ([how to ignore tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6481/how-to-actually-ignore-certain-tags)). The math that you like is as part of mathematics (and as important) as Calc2 and linear algebra homework are. Closing those questions don't solve the drowning problem, it only bias the website.

Comment: @user152732 "The website already has a tag for homework questions." I think you should keep up with recent events if you want to have meaningful discussions on meta. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what and the linked threads. It's a bit hard to take what you say seriously after that. A bit funny that your comment was upvoted almost immediately, too...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sad day for you, then.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Of course not! I mean a sad day for you when the tag was eliminated. That was the solution to your problem of drowning.

Comment: @user152732 Okay, English isn't my first language so sometimes I'm confused. I was in favor of deleting the homework tag. I have nothing against homework questions on principle. But I have something against boring, no-effort questions; these are often homework, but not always, and homework questions are often like that, but not always. So no, it was definitely not a solution, compounded with the fact that use of the tag was erratic at best (many users didn't use it even when it was a homework question).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Erratic tagging happens always, for all tags. But enforcing right tagging is not so difficult, since almost everyone can edit tags. Compare that to the will-never-end war of closing questions. Just saying. Everyone sees what they want to see.

Comment: @user152732: Enforcing the homework tag was impossible. That is one of the reasons it wasn't useful.  There are several meta posts where this was discussed.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That is likely, given that the name of the tag and the use that it was intended for had no relation to each other. I have given zero thought to what would be the right name for classifying the 'boring', 'simpler' types of questions. Perhaps 'ditactic-exercise', 'exercise', 'text-book-exercise'. These are too long or complicated. I can certainly see a poster disagreeing to someone else tagging his/her with 'homework'. "It is not a homework!" (even though it is text-book material)- they may think.

Comment: The ostracism of these types of questions, on the other hand,... Beware of it and what the future of this website could become. There is a demand, a market, for those types of questions. There is also an importance for those questions to get answers. If this website completely blocks them. Another website will fill the market. There is a difference between specially handling those question in **this** website and turning this website into a place for nice questions only (MathOverflow/ArtOfProblemSolving).

Comment: @user152732: If another website fills that role and leaves us to deal with interesting questions, I say ["Mission f#¤%¤%& accomplished"](http://xkcd.com/810/). And, no, filtering by tag is not a good solution, because even low level tags contain enjoyable questions. The problem is the heavily skewed distribution of the incoming questions towards the banal. We aren't exactly ostracizing a Perikles here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sure. Just make sure to change the [Welcome sign in your front door](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) so that it matches the interior decoration. For example: "*any level*" That is very untrue. A primary school student can't even think posting anything here. "*There is no chit-chat*", not easy to avoid if one has to post attempt, effort, and the constant comments of 'what did you try?'.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen About ostracizing a Perikles. I would meditate that a little. There is an immense value for Mathematical culture allowing the contact between mathematicians and students of every level. In an interview Vladimir Arnold was talking about it. It is an easy-to-find one online. In this effort the 'elite', those that know a little more math, don't need much help finding their way around, finding the nice problems, their pleasure. On the other hand, there is much to gain from helping those who are lost.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen By the way. There is nothing more simple than taking banal (but well formulated question) and tagging them as such and filter it if you don't want to see it. I am sure there is plenty of space in the servers for them. It is a lot less work than getting personally offended by those questions, warring constantly about showing effort or not, tons of discussion in Meta. Appropriately tagged and filtered, each user can choose to answer them or let them rot there untouched. Every question will get an answer, if it has one.

Comment: In my view far too many questions get closed. Supplying an answer in a comment is the proper response in such cases, and in the past I have made a point of doing so. In an effort to avoid the level of frustration that caused me to leave the site for almost a year, I am making an effort to ignore such questions altogether this time around, but my opinion hasn’t changed one iota.

Comment: Look at the futility of this very same post. What could be a solution? Eliminating comments for questions on hold? Then the question can't hardly get improved. Closing accounts, flagging, deleting? Those are only patches. As long as the student asking and someone answering have a communication channel of any sort. Questions will be answered. It is all too sad having a much more simpler solution: tagging/classifying and filtering. **Plus enjoying your zone of comfort without hating the one of others.**

Comment: @user152732 Primary school students should not be posting anything here; the site's Terms of Service require users to be at least 13 years old. Including one's thoughts on the problem being posed in a question is not chit-chat.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Scream at the moon all you want, and call it cheese. That will not change what it is and how it works. "Primary school" is figurative. I have seen my own graduate students, very competent, and old enough come here and get well-formulated questions closed because they only posted the question. Then wasted hours and lines of chit-chat before the math really began being done.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii But again, a competent graduate student don't worries me as much. They will manage. I am more interested in my dumbest, sorry less prepared, calculus student to have welcoming spaces that can save him, sorry or her. Cultivating mathematical culture is there where it happens.

Comment: @user152732: I don't agree with all the closings (check out the previous threads and my answers therein for more details). The problematic cases are those where it is evident that the askers problems run much deeper than the scope of the current question. We cannot reproduce textbooks on demand here. It might be better (=intellectually honest) to use the "too broad" close reason. I'm sorry about to hear of the bad experience your grad students had. That is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Oh, you seem to have left. Too bad.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "Closing accounts, flagging, deleting? Those are only patches."

Comment: @Kar: I didn't understand what you wanted to say to me? In case you haven't noticed I am not the most aggressive close voter in these parts. I guess it was my turn to act as the lightning rod.

Comment: @GerryMyerson *Or maybe [they] just give up on Mathematics altogether, and go do something else.* That's a bit dramatic. If a user storms off the site and out of mathematics just because they can't cope with some baseline feedback, they have more problems than we can solve. I don't think we're obligated to take pains to retain such users.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On behalf of other lightning rods, I salute you. (Not directed only at Jyrki ->) I notice the question in question is now reopened, too. Huh. Imagine that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was not implying anything about you. You observed that the account *user152732* was deleted. I was just quoting something that account said above. That closing accounts is only a patch, to give an example of how patches are used around here instead of actual solutions.

Comment: @rschwieb Not immediately closing an ill posed question by a new user is not 'taking pains to retain them', but more like 'not taking pains to kick them out'.  When I registered here I thought this would be an inclusive community to counteract the air of exclusivity of the mathematics community which has harmed it so much with the public.  It seems I was wrong about this place and will be respectfully taking my leave.

Comment: Dear @guest : Letting poor questions stand *is* a tangible cost, and tolerating that cost *is* taking pains. Putting question "on hold" is hardly an invitation to leave: it's a minimal mechanism to promote improvement of the question. This could only be perceived as "exclusive" only if one is determined to ignore the conventions of a community and get hysterical when they can't have their own way. But I can understand general feelings of frustration during the acclimation process to a new community. Typically this passes rather quickly. Anyhow, you're welcome back any time. Regards

Comment: @guest The snobs among the mathematicians tend to be the most visible, but they are neither the majority nor the best part of the community. This website has (still) a lot of ways to give the necessary help to those who need it most regardless of how much disdain and aggression some can welcome them with. You can begin counting from the guy with the most (SE)*reputation* around, who you almost never see closing anything, to hordes of others with less (SE)*reputation*. The most competent ones are never the ones that expend their time being mean to students.

Comment: This is also highly related to a [question I asked earlier](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10852/29335). Closure simply shouldn't be a dirty word. Closure isn't permanent. It's nothing to get worked up about. We just need to be better about communicating this.

Comment: @rschwieb As long as closing is used when "You haven't show us your work" it will always mean "We believe you are a lazy person that want us to do your work". That is a nasty welcome in every context. Try it in person sometime with peers or seniors in your department (not with students because with students you always have authority and can be mean all you want they will always come back because they need you).

Comment: @Kar It might seem nasty at first, but once one hears the ethical and practical reasons for using this "time out" mechanism, one should see the sense in the tool. And after that, even a *tiny bit* of effort is usually enough to vaccinate a question against closure. It's an easy requirement to satsify, and I think anyone who isn't truly looking for free homework handouts can easily satisfy this requirement. Only the truly exploitative users are the ones who have anything to worry about, in terms of facing a lot of troubles due to closure.

Comment: @rschwieb The truly exploitative users will always get what they want. They just have to pretend anything they are told they must say, and as you said *a tiny bit* is enough. Making students work is a quest that an online website intended for questions "in any level" will never achieve. Teachers in the classroom designing the right evaluation systems are the only ones that can do anything successful about it. Meanwhile everyone is received here with the rude, "nasty at first" welcome that serves no purpose and achieves nothing but being rude and patronizing.

Comment: @kar : `The truly exploitative users will always get what they want.` True, we can't prevent that entirely. But it is silly to argue that this means we should ignore blatant cases. It's like suggesting countries ought not have national borders because someone will always sneak across. As far as I know, minimal requirements on post quality do deter and/or improve the worst kinds of posts.

Comment: @Kar `achieves nothing but being rude and patronizing.` This is a pretty melodramatic. Like I said earlier, if someone can't handle a minimum of feedback when they put a post out there, they don't really have any business soliciting such feedback. A person posting in good faith should have very little trouble with closures after being through an on-hold loop once or twice.

Comment: @Kar `Meanwhile everyone is received here with the rude, "nasty at first" welcome`. This is hard to believe, but in the same time I have to admit that such things happens, but basically due to the poorly asked questions.

Comment: @user26857 I am sorry, but this is not true. A question, perfectly written and clear, but that happens to be simple is being received with the same bad welcome. Very often people just vote to close and carry on. Just explore "is:q closed:1" or the activity log of users like Rafflesia arnoldii, or Davide Giraudo and a handful of others. It is just nasty. The good thing is that it is just a handful of people as I was telling user *guest*. But those actions are very visible, visible for the newcomers and those who still need to learn math; the most important people.

Comment: @rschwieb I agree with you. But what is a blatant case? A post that contains a list of 5 exercises, I agree. A good reply can be "please post the questions separately" and close. A post that contains a simple but single, and well formulated question? Those can come from any type of student. It is rude to welcome them with the useless, and spammy question (that mostly has spammy answers) of "what have you tried?" that begins the relationship with the new user by assuming ill from them.

Comment: @Kar So, if a student posts his homework here, then who are we to ask him what he tried? Solve the homework and shut up!

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you are right in part of that answer. "Who are we to ask what he tried?" Nobody, nobody at all. We have really no power whatsoever to prevent it. Thinking that we are is only arrogance from us. The parts that are wrong are: "student" It not always is. That is an assumption that we are making. Sometimes it is a researcher from a different area, or a good student studying areas too advanced for them. Another part that is wrong is "solve it and shut up". No one can force you to solve it. Just move on to the next question.

Comment: @user26857 Moreover, if a student posts his homework here, and someone solves it (not those who don't want to solve it, those should just leave the question alone), just someone else happens to solve it. What went wrong? Let us think about it. Or better, let us think and list in our mind what are the consequences first without pre-judgement. And then think whether they are really bad consequences or not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Indeed things were unpleasant a year ago. They are now worse. And vandals are now reaching back well into the past to expunge questions and answers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott (I've never seen a post where you explain why left the site. Instead I've seen other users asking this and maybe getting frustrated that nobody answered them. Coming now and saying such things is like you want to play a game after the game is over.) If you and others want this site to be a homework solving machine, this is your own business. But among such many things you seem to neglect a crucial one: the lower and lower quality of the questions we are witnessing nowadays.

Comment: @user26857: I disagree with almost everything in your comment. (1) There is nothing in the least improper about mentioning in passing why I left if it is relevant, as it is, and I am under no obligation to make a general announcement. (2) I don’t particular want MSE to be a ‘homework solving machine’, but helping students who are struggling with homework is a good thing and a legitimate function of the site. (3) I don’t even think that your ‘crucial’ thing is true. I see very little difference from a year ago.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott (1) You were the one who mentioned that left the site as a protest against God knows what. (2) Nobody can't be helped if doesn't make any effort in the right direction. (3) Maybe you don't want to perceive the sad truth.

Comment: @user26857: (1) It should be clear from my comments, at least in general terms, what I found frustrating. (2) Posting here is a start in the right direction and doesn’t deserve the nasty reception that it too often gets. (3) I have a considerably longer observational baseline than the ten months that you appear to have, and I probably look at more questions than you do as well. What’s more, since I was away for almost a year, I can see very clearly what changes have occurred: for me they’re sudden, not gradual. I do not see any significant decrease in quality. The increase in the number ...

Comment: ... of poorly phrased questions appears to be pretty much in line with the increase in the total number of questions.

Comment: @user26857 You say `Nobody can't be helped if doesn't make any effort in the right direction.`. That is an assumption, a **bad faith assumption** with which a group of (self-righteous) people are receiving **all** questions that don't include **chit-chat** about what they have tried. This is the sad truth. The student that comes and posts here is, at the very least, making the clear effort of coming here and post a question. If the question is simple no-one here is forced to answer it **and no-one has the right to feel angry if someone else answers it.**

Comment: `The student that comes and posts here is, at the very least, making the clear effort of coming here and post a question.` Should I laugh or should I cry?

Comment: @user26857 You do whatever you want. We all have free will. You choose to the person who assumes bad will from posters. I am just letting you know that there are others that don't make such a choice and how little we need to feel good about other people.

Comment: @user192486 I wish you good luck in your choices, and welcome to the site.

Comment: @user26857 I have been in this website for over 6 years. Don't think that the only ways of taking advantage of the website features by using it in the standard ways.

Comment: @user26857: This website started in July 2010.

Comment: @JonasMeyer **SE** started much earlier than that.

Comment: @user26857 If you were more interested in **this** website you would focus in what is important about this conversation. If you are not able to have mature conversation this is the end of it with you. For you I have this answer to your original question: **There is no way to stop us, and in particular me, from giving answers to those who seek it.** I will answers, in any space available all questions I am able and willing to answer. Yes, the comment section of questions on hold is one of them.

Comment: @user192486 Go for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of locking the question (which is a moderator-only action, and is rare), we cannot prevent comments from being added to a non-locked, non-deleted question.

But we can delete the question. In the specific case, auto-deletion should take care of things; when it does not apply, one needs 10K delete votes.

Generally, the cleanup of closed questions has been going better in second half of this year than in the past. Compared to the statistics I gave in [How to repair the close-delete pipeline?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16255/), the deletion activity more than doubled (there are 300 active delete votes right now, compared to 125 back then). The number of questions on the [death row](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1%20duplicate%3A0%20locked%3A0) has not grown very much, indicating that most closed questions get taken care of: improved and reopened, or deleted.

Comment: In my opinion the deletion is irrelevant. More important is to prevent such things, but I don't know how, and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @user26857 There is no way to prevent it; some users even do it purposefully. The only other thing that can be done is flagging the comment, and if enough people do it the comment will be deleted. But that seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Mods are spending days before deleting a comment, so this is not practical at all.

Comment: @user26857 [If I understand this correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work), the comment will be auto-deleted if it gathers enough flags. But yes, moderator's time is finite and they often have more important things to do.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Not for every type of comment flag. It's pretty complicated, and documentation is incomplete, perhaps on purpose. Ilmari Karonen [tried science](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237368/) to figure this out.

Answer (score -8):

You say you don't think it is appropriate to answer closed questions into the comments. But it is also not appropriate to close a question before the OP is given the chance to improve it. The question you link to is a perfect example of that.

Comment: A question is put on hold with the expectation that the OP will improve it. Having both processes -- of the question being edited and answers being posted -- run in parallel creates a mess of mismatched content.

Comment: Yet the OP of that question improved it 19 hours ago and you haven't reversed your closing vote.

Comment: Any 5 users can vote to reopen, it need not be the people who voted to close.  19 hours ago it was improved, so why don't users who want it open vote to open?

Comment: FWIW I just voted to reopen. Will expect it to be reopened soon. But agree with Rafflesia, the point of putting on hold is to signal the need to improve loud and clear. If only the posters who reacted strongly would work with the system rather than against it :-(

Comment: FWIW, the OP there made a mistake (can't blame her/him for not knowing how the review queue works of course), (s)he made [an insignificant edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1015052/4) and the question was put in the review queue, where it was rightly decided to [leave it closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/299316) (now one sees how the question currently looks, but the reviewers saw revision 4). After that came the edit that made it reopenable. But a question gets into the review queue only once, chance wasted :(

Comment: @Daniel: And that seems to be exactly the right use for the reopen requests thread! When a significant edit is made, and the question doesn't get into the review queue.

Comment: Indeed @Asaf. Should be mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17262/the-reopen-request-thread-and-closures-on-meta).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do questions get put into the reopen queue after a single vote has been cast to reopen, in the same way that close voting works?

Comment: @EricStucky [a reopen vote will add a question to the reopen queue if it isn't already in the queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/259867)