# Deleting questions with answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A few days ago I posted an answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712921/simple-module-question). After that the original poster deleted it. I undeleted it because it is a terrible idea to delete questions which people have taken the time to answer — the most likely reason for this deletion was cheating on a test or something like that, as far as one could tell, and vandalizing one's own content is reasonably frowned upon.

A couple of days after that, I happened to need myself something similar to what I knew I had written in than answer and I searched for it. It turned out the question has been deleted by other users. I undeleted as I always do when questions on which people have expended effort in writing answers are deleted.

It was deleted again, again by the votes of people.

I **honestly** cannot imagine what reasons motivate people to delete a question which has an answer. The question is probably not the best question in the history of the site, the answer is surely not the best answer in the history of the site: sure. But what argument a sensible mind can come up with that decides that it is better **not** to have the question with its answer than to have it is simply beyond me.

I have spent many hours producing answers on this site, as many others have, and the result of our collective effort is a quite amazing amount of extremely useful information. I have often found myself googling things and finding the answers in posts I have myself written already years ago, both here and MathOverflow, and I have gotten quite an extraordinary number of times thanks from people I know and people I don't know for things that I have written here that were useful to them.

Now, if for whatever byzantine reason users are going to begin deleting useful content I for one simply cannot continue  producing it and I cannot in good faith suggest —as I systematically do— to other people that they come and answer questions, for I actually cannot be sure that the effort put into doing that will not simply be wasted.

So:

> Are we to value the effort people put in producing the content that actually makes this site or not?

It is surprising to me —and actually very sad— that I do not know what the consensus on this question is. I can vividly remember a time when I would have not even imagined the possibility of needing to ask this.

**PS:** Just to pick an example of another answer of mine (I am entirely sure that there are hundreds of great answers written by many users posted on bad questions throughout the site), should [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73262/proving-that-mn-sqrt2-is-dense-in-r) be deleted? It is certainly no better in what respects context and what not that the one I linked above —I'd go as far as saying that it is significantly worse, in fact, and I am completely sure that it is well below our standards. That it is an old question has proven not to be a reason for not looking at it with a critical eye, so: should it be deleted? Are we prepared to live with such a low quality question on our site? I'd only ask to be notified by whoever casts the last delete vote on it, so that I can copy the text of my answer and put it somewhere else, for it has been very useful to me since I wrote it.

**PS:** I got curious. [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/835119) are some 1000 questions which should keep us entertained.

Comment: Mariano: Why does this issue, and your concern about it, and your surprise, only apparent when it happens to questions you've answered?  Why do you only visit meta when something happens to your answers?  Your last post on meta was  about your outrage that a answer of yours (a reference) was marked as a link only question.  That you are surprised by and unaware of the tension/contention on the issue of deleting very poor questions, surprises me.  In any case: be careful what you choose to answer; if it's a problem statement question, no effort, likely homework, don't answer it to begin with.

Comment: [Here is a related discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I posted a long time ago on an old account when my views were different. I'm deeply conflicted on this matter; yes, it wastes the time of the answerer and that is extremely frustrating. On the other hand, many questions don't (IMHO) deserve to be answered because they are just doing someone's work for them without any engagement from the asker. At the moment I'm inclined to think that deletion is a necessary evil.

Comment: When I see people delete questions with answers I always undelete them. This is the very first time I have seen in almost 8 years that after the original poster deletes a question it is deleted by other users.

Comment: One work around is that someone repost the same question, with better context, and then you answer the new question or merge the two. Some users might disagree and still vote to close. But they can only vote once, and that gives your answer more protection.

Comment: The point of this post is to know whether it makes sense for me personally to continue answering questions and to ask others to do so or not. It is very simple, I think. If it is a "necessary evil" to delete useful and probably valuable content produced by users, then I can certainly live with that and simply stop producing it myself and suggesting others to do so.

Comment: Also, I think that a distinction needs to be drawn between homework-mill questions where people are rapidly answering the *same* calculus questions over and over again for reputation, and questions that are mathematically difficult or interesting on their own. I think very little is lost in the first case, but the second case should really be much more carefully considered. Also, to try and think towards a resolution, @Mariano: is there a method of quality control for these type of questions that you *would* advocate, short of deleting them?

Comment: It's not a black and white issue Mariano.  Your answers are very much welcome;  just use a bit more discretion in what you answer.

Comment: I very much agree with @user296602, in their comments here.

Comment: @user296602, when a question exists, is sensible and has been answered, I posit there is no argument in the universe that can justify deleting it: in what possible way would **not** having the question/answer be better than having it? In what way is the site better by **not** having that question/answer pair online and viewable by everyone?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I'm sorry, but your last comment strikes me as posted in bad faith.  You clearly have not read any of the comments/inputs some users have suggested.

Comment: "The point of this post is to know whether it makes sense for me personally to continue answering questions" I don't think it makes sense for you personally to continue answering *bad* questions.

Comment: @amWhy, well: if someone googles something, it is quite binary: she finds an answer here to her question or not. When someone gives us her time and good will to write an answer here, it is also quite binary: do we value it or not. One can argue for two ages on "tensions" and what not (I am sincerely not interested in that) but the end result is  of a very binary nature.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Low quality questions start off a cycle of decaying standards. A user writes a very informative answer to a non-context homework dump; people find it through Google, and think that it's ok to do the same and post a bunch of low-effort things. In that sense, getting rid of the poorly stated questions may be a necessary evil in terms of keeping the site from becoming a do-my-homework service.

Comment: @ZacharySelk, what you think is that it makes no sense for me to continue answering what you think are bad questions.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that there are many users who are driven *away* from the site because of the low quality questions. I know that I'm less inclined to answer than I used to be, because there just seems to be a deluge of do-my-homework posts with people gobbling up reputation as quickly as they can. So while your frustration is completely understandable, please keep in mind that many of us have similar but opposite feelings.

Comment: @mariano well not me, necessarily. But if you are worried about losing your answer it doesn't make sense for you to answer questions that I (or others with the power to delete) would consider bad questions.

Comment: That is a slightly long winded way of saying that it does not make sense for me to answer questions *tout court*. I can certainly live with that consensus.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  If that's the decision you've arrived at, I respect it.  But your last comment does not represent the feedback given here in comments.

Comment: @user296602, well, the point of my post is that there *can* be a standard: putting the value of the content our users produce above the our beloved byzantine "tensions". I am asking if we are to take such a standard or not, mostly in order to decide if there is any point in answering questions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I doubt that a reasonable standard or consensus is going to come from this; otherwise, it would have been reached years ago. And I frankly doubt that the comments here (from myself too!!) represent average community views; a lot of people here (myself included) downvote, closevote, or delete very frequently. Perhaps the fairest compromise is to repost a new question that actually has some context or motivation and copy your answer there. That tends to be reasonably well received.

Comment: @Mariano  Since you refuse to consider any feedback, and remain fixated on receiving one binary output, there probably isn't any point for you answering questions. There is very much a point in answering, if you use a bit of discretion in what you answer.

Comment: Think of it in this way: when I or others google, will they find the content I can produce or not. If yes, then it makes sense for me (and, I assume, others with similar motivations) to put it here. If no, it doesn't. Surely, the way such binary result is reached involves lots of grays and tensions and what not. But after all that dust is settled, there are two outcomes: either the content is accessible or not. Google results do not come with links to the discussion of why a question was good, and more importantly, there are no google results at all pointing to deleted content.

Comment: @user296602, that posting a new question and copying there the answer be a reasonable way to deal with this should probably be an indication that something is amiss... But hey, it may well be the way we decide this should be done. As I said, I can live with that.

Comment: "that posting a new question and copying there the answer be a reasonable way to deal with this should probably be an indication that something is amiss." Unfortunately this is how it works for now, at least users from both sides are okay with... @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: @user296602, I am prepared to bet a beer that while users have left for the bad quality of some questions, immensely more have come and remained for the good quality of our answers. My question is, precisely, how to weigh those two things.

Comment: Answering a bad question is very much like building a ranch home in a floodplain. Nobody should be surprised by the consequences. I think there's a little wiggle room for exceptions when bad questions get valuable answers, or there is some peculiarity about the bad question that makes it seem worth keeping, and that can be handled case-by-case. Generally granting a sort of immunity to bad questions with answers seems like a bad idea though: it sends a message to the poster that no-effort will sometimes be rewarded, and it sends a message to rep farmers that they have secure income.

Comment: +1 from me, although it is mainly to get the question over score +3 needed to be displayed in community bulletin - since I think it might be useful if more users notice this discussion.

Comment: "I undeleted as I always do when questions on which people have expended effort in writing answers are deleted." The [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) may be out of date, but (at least for normal users) it says the protocol is tomerge the question to a better one if possible, and it is also commonplace to create a new, better question, for the sake of saving answers. However, it does not recommend voting to undelete questions for their answers nor does it recommend avoiding to vote to delete for their answers.

Comment: "Are we to value the effort people put in producing the content that actually makes this site or not?" If you had followed either of the previously mentioned procedures, this would not be the case. There is nothing to prevent you from saving your own effort nor preventing someone else from saving your effort if they find it valuable.

Comment: Mmm, perhaps I did not mean to say posting new questions for the sake of saving answers was commonplace, but it is certainly not a new thing.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I have no doubt that answers on bad quality questions attract some people to MSE. But I expect that mostly to be people who post bad quality questions, expecting them to be answered.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I undeleted the question when the deletion was done by the post owner, as I and many others have done in maaaaany instances of people trying to delete a question used to cheat on a test or something like that. When a handful of experienced users *again* deleted the content, I did not undelete it: that would have been really a stupid idea — because using mod powers to counter the actions of users is a catastrophic idea in general, but most of all because at that point it is clear to me that the thing to look at is clearly not the question but the policy.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, it's not a new thing. I've done it myself on occasion since this site exists. What is something somewhat new, I think, is the consensus (at least, among a number of users with power to do it) that deleting a question with useful content is fine. I know that the help center does not say "avoid voting to delete questions which contain useful content and if at all possible take actions to preserve it, maybe asking a new question or what not": that we apparently could use such an indication in whatever Holy Scrolls that contain our policy is precisely what this post is about!

Comment: Some time ago I would have laughed if someone told me that an addendum on the help center with text essentially equivalent to "use common sense" could be useful. O tempora, o mores!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You have pretty valid points (e.g., the fact that there is no notification for deletion of a question. This coupled with the inherent subjectiveness of what constitutes a good question can make it laborious to guarantee that good content stays on the site, as you very well point out in the comments of some answers). Why contaminate a valid and pertinent post with irrelevant and arguably insulting commentary such as "what argument a sensible mind can come up with (...)"?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez "When a handful of experienced users again deleted the content, I did not undelete it: that would have been really a stupid idea — because using mod powers to counter the actions of users is a catastrophic idea in general, but most of all because at that point it is clear to me that the thing to look at is clearly not the question but the policy." I assume you do not mean the [third time](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2712921/timeline#history_cfdcc075-7839-456b-b117-e622ec956247) you undeleted the post after it was deleted by 3 users?

Comment: "What is something somewhat new, I think, is the consensus (at least, among a number of users with power to do it) that deleting a question with useful content is fine." This runs on the assumption that those who voted to delete the question saw your answer and believed it contained useful content. Whether or not this is the case I do not know, but I can say that your answer only ascertained one upvote, which is the only concrete evidence I have for your case.

Comment: Personally, when I vote to delete a question, I do not generally look at the answers, or even whether there are answers.  Perhaps this is because I view asking good questions and getting useful answers to be the main purpose of this site, rather than making a repository of answers. Even worse, bad questions *prevent* people from asking good questions, if the bad questions are viewed as pre-existing duplicates that cause the new questions to be closed.  If the site will be a repository, in my opinion it should be a repository for *excellent* questions with *excellent* answers

Comment: A discussion on rather similar topic from 2014: [Under what circumstances is it appropriate to delete a question that has received a good answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16462)

Answer (score 9):

> I am prepared to bet a beer that while users have left for the bad quality of some questions, immensely more have come and remained for the good quality of our answers. My question is, precisely, how to weigh those two things.

I posit that it is obvious that we do not have to 'weigh' or 'balance' those two things. We can have our cake and eat it too. Like this: If you have posted an answer that you feel is useful and cannot be found easily elsewhere, then you can simply copy it over to a good question (of your own), where you have the complete freedom to tailor the question perfectly to your answer. After all, the SE system [explicitly encourages this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/answering). Doing this have the following benefits:

1. The question meets the site standards as given in [the FAQ everyone is supposed to read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959).
2. The answer is preserved for posterity.
3. The question can be as general/interesting/cogent as you can make it and answer to.
4. Cheaters and help-sappers are not rewarded with abetment or spoon-feeding.

All of the above implies that site quality goes up. Which is something we all want, right? $\ddot\smile$

I shall also mention that what I am suggesting is not at all new; it has been done before like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239566) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912552).

---

Update: After a brief search, I also found the following examples of preserving good answers to low-quality old questions.

- [This lousy old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202924) was merged into [this better new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2647385) after [this discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=42814609#42814609).
- [This bad old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118030) had its four answers all moved to [this good new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600903). In fact, in this case the asker of the new question deleted his question after it was marked as duplicate, and after discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=42466849#42466849) it was agreed that the better question should be undeleted and the old one was flagged for merging.
- [This poor old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1569527) had its four answers all moved to [this good new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690797) as mentioned [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=39929224#39929224).

There are many more examples, as anyone who is sufficiently interested can find for themselves.

Comment: Has been done before? You link to a question by Martin with an answer by Brian...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh sorry wrong example then. It was kind of similar, but there are examples which have been transferred to a much better question and then self-answered. I recall even moderators helping with the transfer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you look at the first comment under the linked post, it is indeed a repost of a question that was closed and deleted. (In fact, it went through a few rounds of [deletion and undeletion](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1422534/revisions).)

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. That clarifies.

Comment: I know this has been done: I've even done it myself quite a few times. But this has nothing to do, really, with what I am asking. I could imagine a policy that asked the *people that vote to delete* a question with answers to start a new "better" question and copy things there, so as to preserve content at the same time as cleansing the site of the bad seed. But you're proposing instead extra hoops for the people *who produce useful content* to follow, then the natural thing is for them to not only not follow your hoops but to simply not produce the content —add friction and see what happens.

Comment: I honestly really don't think the particular question on which my answer was posted to be that bad —the 1000 questions that are found by the SQL query I added to the post are manifestly worse, for example, and our crusaders for context have not seemed to care much. But *other* people did, and that, according to you, should be handled by *me* doing something. Notice that one is not even notified when a question on which one has an answer is deleted.

Comment: One has to police one's answers permanently everafter in order to know that one's effort in writing them is not values less that a quest for context and, thereby, discarded? — What do you do on Mondays? — Oh Mondays I go through my MSE answers to see if a handful of people have decided that having the question on which they are posted is worse than the good of having the answer and ask new questions, add some made up content and motivation, and copy and paste the old answer.

Comment: @Mariano  If you feel the questions you answer in particular should  excluded/exempted from deletion, even acknowledging the questions may be crappy, then you probably shouldn't be moderating here.  Again, as I said from the beginning, it seems this only becomes an issue to you when a question *you answered* is deleted.  Welcome to the club!  I personally do not think that questions asked and answered 5+ years ago should be targeted, because this site has evolved.  I've lost many answers due to the deletion of the corresponding question.  It's not pleasant.

Comment: Your answer is about what people writing answers should do —effectively proposing they do more— while my question is about what people voting to delete content should do. Quite orthogonal.

Comment: @amWhy, I generally do not watch the list of deletions. I honestly was surprised when after having undeleted a question which was obviously vandalized by its poster I found it deleted again by experienced users. I would not have noticed if it had not been my  own answer and, by chance, I'd have googled for it a few days after writing it. I cringe at the idea that this has happened to answers write by other users.

Comment: I cannot imagine where you got the idea that "feel the questions [I] answer in particular should excluded/exempted from deletion" but I am not surprised that you got it — after all this time, I have come to *expect* you to attempt to divert all issues  by assuming they are of that nature, as you always do.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I understand that. And I see that you were upset, as are a good many users, me included, when I've lost an answer due to the deletion of a question.  But I try to separate my own disappointment, not take it personally.

Comment: @Mariano Since you want to continue acting like BD, attempting to divert the issues by assuming you can play ad-hominem with me, I'm done here.

Comment: @amWhy, If you are content with having effort you expended on answers lost because their corresponding questions have been deleted, all the power to you. My post, though, is me wondering how many people are willing to spend time and effort in doing something that can be easily discarded. With your data point, now we know the number of such people is positive. What is strange to me is that you seem to think that many others share your willingness to do things for others to destroy them.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  Other than that, if you choose to continue to attack me personally, I can't stop you, given your position.

Comment: @amWhy, it is not an ad-hominem. Many times already you have attributed things to pettiness and what not, just as you did in your very first on this post. I am just saying that that is not surprising to me, because by now we have interacted with each other for a long time. It is not an "ad-hominem attack" or an attack of any other form to weigh what you say to me according to my experience of interacting with you. What else could I do?

Comment: That it has been more than ***three years*** since you've asked a question on meta, and then, within one month, post two rants about how unfair the site treats you, and acting like you've been rip van winkle until now, says more than I can say.  Cheers.

Comment: You saw in that comment an attack to you personally? Really? Well, now *that* I did not expect.

Comment: Just as you imagine that because you are ok with the content you produce to be discarded, many others (most of the others?) will also be ok with it, I assume that many others are not ok with that, just as I am not ok with it. It is probable that your position in that respect is rooted on a much more optimistic view of humanity than mine, but is not in essence of a different nature than mine.

Comment: [Actually, three years in which you posted nothing.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/274/mariano-su%c3%a1rez-%c3%81lvarez).  No general user ever needs to contribute to meta.  But in case you've forgotten, you, Mariano, are a moderator of this site who, from the last two posts, has revealed someone not terribly involved on meta, and slack on voicing anything other than a couple examples that affected *you.*  Welcome aboard, but what you've evidenced, especially in your absence and reappearance to get your work reinstated, is your general apathy, save when anything affects you.

Comment: Well, in three years I had neither received a flag on an answer saying that a bibliographic reference to a standard book on a subject is bad nor noticed that experienced users were deleting questions with sensible answers in the way they did. The "tensions" have always been there, but *now* I have noticed —because I saw it up close— they are at a point in which content is actually at risk of being discarded. As I wrote in the post, not too long ago I would not have imagined this to be a possibility.

Comment: I love the "you want continue to act like BD", by the way.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  No, I'm not "okay", but I've accepted it when the question I answered was I very poor question.  I don't like it; I momentarily feel pissed off, I work hard to restrain myself from solicitating askers who use this site as a "do my work for me" service, and free at that.  You've never seen me running to meta in outrage because "my answers are different, better, worth preserving forever, even if the questions that were deleted were no longer much I have to be proud about.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Let me address the points you raised in your comments. (1) Your hypothetical policy is a bad idea since it puts the totally unnecessary burden of cleanup on the wrong users. Users who produce useful content should can do so but not at the **expense** of site quality, otherwise the FAQ is meaningless. (2) I did not propose any **extra** hoops. There is no reason to keep poor questions around, **based on** the site guidelines for good questions, otherwise we would be **inconsistent**. [continued]

Comment: (3) Thanks for your SQL search. Your claim that 'crusaders for context' have not cared much' is a misrepresentation, and for the sake of discussion don't associate others with killers (crusaders killed innocent people). (4) I'm surprised you are not notified that your answer is deleted; that is unfortunate, but does not change the fact that bad questions should not be answered at all. (5) If you find that a good question has been deleted, by all means bring it up for undeletion.

Comment: @Mariano And I had to laugh when you state you suggest that we have interacted enough to know me; where, except for the last month, we have rarely, if ever, "interacted" You're not around enough for me to have interacted directly with you.   Except for engaging with you in your two rants this month.  Now I will try to keep my word to end your endless self-justifications.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You said "If you are content with having effort you expended on answers lost because their corresponding questions have been deleted..."  I'm not sure that anyone is saying that they are exactly "content" with such an outcome, but it is a possibility.  Once you write an answer, that content belongs to the community.  The community could very well decide that your great content is attached to terrible content that needs to be deleted.  Such is life.  If you don't want to "waste your effort," perhaps you should get a blog?

Comment: @user21820 With regards to 4. of your answer, if you remake the question right away, isn't there a strong possibility that the cheater will just search for the question (on google, even) and find it? I know that cheaters are known to be not very smart, but I think that if we want to guarantee 4., it would perhaps be useful to suggest waiting a bit before remaking the question.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Frankly, while I don't want to enable cheating, I also don't want to adjudicate what is and what is not cheating---while a poorly written question may come from an attempt to cheat, it isn't my job to make that judgement.  If a question has interesting mathematical content, but is poorly worded, I am happy with someone opening a new question to explore that content.  If the original questioner was attempting to cheat and is aided by that new question, that is an unfortunate side effect, but one that is ultimately orthogonal to the goals of this site.

Comment: @xander, it does **not** belong to the community. It is licensed to the community. It is licensed to the community using a very generous license. That is a quite important point, and you and everyone should be clear on it. Of course, the community can decide to no longer take advantage of the license and stop publishing the content — but the owner of each post here is the poster.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Copyright licensing pedantry aside, the content is never entirely gone and can always be accessed by (at the very least) the originator of the content.  However the choice of whether or not to make that content broadly available on this site belongs to the community (in is in this sense that I mean "the content belongs to the community").  Your content lives on top of a soapbox. 
 The Community is free to remove that box.  You are free to take this content and publish it on a blog of your own if you really feel that it is so important that it should be preserved.

Comment: It is slightly boring to have people not be able to come up with nothing but arguments based on one's pettiness or pedantry. It seems that there is a whole school :-/

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Your concern is addressed by point 3. When a good replacement question is posted, it is very likely to be more general and interesting than the original lousy one. Thus it would still take a cheater some effort to figure out how to apply the new question to his/her own. So point 4 will be achieved most of the time. In any case it's not the main focus, but a happy side-effect. From a random sample of confirmed cheating attempts, it is clear that the vast majority of them are poor questions, so just applying site quality guidelines would automatically reduce cheating success.

Comment: @user21820 Good points.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I agree with what you are saying (I hold to myself that the primary objective of the site is a body of knowledge, and the issues of "cheating" etc are a "quality-of-life" improvement of standards for the site). My point is that for people who are actively trying to prevent cheating possibilities, I think that holding off reposting a question for a day or two would do no harm and possibly prevent the cheating. There is no need to hurry, after all. This is only if they, personally, think that there is an attempt at cheating (**and are willing to**, of course).

Comment: @XanderHenderson To give an example, if I thought any problem of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2722786/59234) was interesting, I would wait a day or two before posting it, because I personally ascertained that this was a cheating attempt. This is not meant to be a rule of any kind, just something to keep in mind if you have the intention of preventing cheating. If not, that is completely fine.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Indeed I also concur with your opinion about holding off answering (in any way) what is quite surely a cheating attempt. It is however not the focus of this Meta question, which is about deletion after answers have already been posted. =)

Comment: @user21820, are those examples you added to your post examples of people who had written answers and when the question got deleted were somehownnotified created,  a new question themselves and moved their answers there, or examples of people that when voting to delete a question becaude it was bad decided it was more sensible to keep the content in another better question? Were the writers of the answers involved at all in that process? Were they themselves the ones that actually went and preserved the content?

Comment: Because if they are examples of people that in cleaning the site of bad questions, decided that the answers were worth preserving despite the question on which they sat and went thru all the hoops needed to preserve them, then I am not at all surprised: that is the behavior I would expect most users to take — that they don't is what motivated my post.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Did you notice Asaf's example that I added, where he literally posted a new question with his answer after the original was deleted? As for the other examples, I included them just to show that one does not have to keep bad questions around. Like many others, I think it is **inconsistent** to say that we want to have quality questions and at the same time not want to delete poor questions. Good answers do **not** magically make bad questions better. The **obvious solution** is for users to not post answers to lousy questions. As a moderator, you should know that...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I have no issues with **old** poor questions being handled via merging if the asker is not a PSQ factory. But I think **new** lousy questions do not deserve that kind of leeway, unless we want Math SE to become a homework factory.

Comment: What you think is that I should not post answers to questions *you* think are lousy questions: in this case I made a judgement call and decided that the question was not that terrible — there are literally thousands of questions on the site that are considerably worse in all respects to the one I answered. If before answering questions users have to consult you, or a group, or read some meta threads, or something then we have a problem, don't we?

Comment: Those examples you linked to show behavior I applaud emphatically — people making a judgement call and seeing that there is something of value to be preserved. It is the seeing exact opposite behavior that led me start this thread.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Concerning the other poorer questions, I didn't disagree with you that there are thousands of other poorer ones. Feel free to list them out (especially the newer ones as per my above remark) in the CRUDE chat-room, and we will certainly look through them. As for what is a poor question. [Math SE's How-To-Ask FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) makes the guidelines quite clear.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Did you notice I emphasized the issue of **moderators** answering **new** and **objectively poor** (as per the FAQ) questions? New users or old questions can be dealt with in the other way so as not to cause much disturbance. And please note the observer bias; you only see what you observe but do not usually notice what happens that has no effect on you.

Comment: You could ask The Powers That Be to mass-delete all the 953 questions my SQL query. It is sureñy impossible that a question with less than 100 characters satisfies those guidelines. That's only from this last year — you can easily edit the query to pick only more recent ones if a year is within the range of what you call old.

Comment: Objectively poor. Heh. Love the concept. In any case I don't understand what relevance has the fact that I am a moderator. If I were not a moderator, and just a passer by who saw an interesting question and who has not studied the part of Leviticus detailing what is a good question, would the people that voted to delete the whole thing be expected to act differently? Was the content deleted because I am a moderator? I have to say that I find that even more surprising than any other ideas I've seen put forward in this post.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: You being a moderator is **not** the crux. It is that new users can reasonably be given **some excuse** to not know the guidelines. Long-time users, and especially moderators, should already know them. Thanks for confirming the objective fact that a question with less than 100 characters cannot satisfy the guidelines. Give the 10k rep users some time to work through the list you provided; you know very well that a fisherman cannot catch all the fish in the sea.

Comment: On one hand, I have not confirmed anything: I simply do not believe that a 100 character long question is necessarily bad — for example, I do not believe the question that brought this up was bad and it is somewhat longer than that. I find any criterion based on the length of the question to be laughable, in fact, and that is the point of the SQL query.

Comment: On the other, knowing the "guidelines" does not certainly mean that one has to follow them in every situation: that would be a rule, not it a guideline. Any guideline which does not ultimately defer to common sense and certain amount of flexibility in order to decide what is a good question and what is not is simply silly, I am afraid. You are putting out abother idea that surprises me: apparently you believe unanimity of criteria is something desirable — what a discouraging position :-/

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Don't set up a strawman. You said "It is sureñy impossible that a question with less than 100 characters satisfies those guidelines.". I said "Thanks for confirming the objective fact that a question with less than 100 characters cannot satisfy the guidelines.". And don't put words into my mouth. I never said unanimity of criteria is desirable. Otherwise I wouldn't even be discussing with you. Furthermore, even among users who do care about quality questions, we have significant disagreement on some questions, and differing views on the best approach in some cases.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Finally, we can see here roughly that the consensus of those who care about site quality is in fact in line with upholding the guidelines. And are you going to admit that we **do care** about the "manifestly worse" questions that you have found by an SQL query (in your own words)? As you speak, many of them are now being cleaned up, and if you are really so interested in that you can help by making a new SQL query that excludes the deleted ones...

Comment: @user21820, in fact, the motivation of mentioning the question about density and the SQL query was a little experiment to see how long it would take for that to happen. Last time I looked, the density question has 4 close votes, all cast after I mentioned it here. I picked that question becaude it would be a great example of what I think is a bad policy.

Comment: Likewise, the SQL query is designed to capture questions which are "bad" buy which in many, many cases I believe it is silly to go and close or whatever.

Comment: Stay on topic, please, @Mariano.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: For the third time I'll repeat that **you** stated it is impossible that a question with less than 100 characters satisfies the guidelines in the How-To-Ask FAQ, and are **manifestly worse** than the one which this Meta question is about. If you don't want to admit that, then there's no point continuing. And whether you think it's a bad thing to delete poor questions is irrelevant to whether it's actually bad for Math SE. If you're going to rely on mere opinion, as I said before the opinions of others here are quite clear.

Answer (score 9):

> Are we to value the effort people put in producing the content that actually makes this site or not?

No, we are to value the *content that actually makes this site*.

We might appreciate and acknowledge the effort put into it, but the *value* lies in the content itself.

Undesirable content that someone put a lot of time into is still undesirable content. That isn't changed if we have empathy for the wasted effort.

---

> if ... users are going to begin deleting useful content I for one simply cannot continue producing it

The point here is a conflict in judgment: you judge some content as "useful", but others judge the same content as "undesirable".

The ideal of the current status quo is that readers should be able to discriminate between questions that will and will not get deleted. That answerers will refrain from wasting time writing undesirable content, and instead devote their efforts towards towards writing desirable content, or towards improving undesirable content to be come desirable content.

You could make a meta post revisiting (yet again) the question of what precisely is desirable. However, you come off as taking the position that is basically "all content is desirable"; if that is the position you wind up advocating for, I expect you'll get little to no sympathy from those invested in trying to maintain quality standards.

Or, you might make a meta post about arguing that the current standards are indiscernible, assuming you actually have trouble doing so. (I expect the result to be that any conflicts you see where you thought something would get closed but it was not is merely because it slipped by unnoticed)

Comment: You *really* understand that I am saying that all content is desirable?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I wasn't sure; I **honestly** can't understand what would motivate people to think so. But my advice still applies; "don't delete anything" simply is not useful feedback to people who are already of the opinion that some things should be deleted.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Are you also of the opinion that all content is *equally* desirable, as at least one user has advocated in the past? If you at least acknowledge some things are more valuable than others, there is potential to have a constructive discussion about how to distinguish content of higher value from that of lower value, with the idea of influencing people who do delete things to be more likely to retain the higher value stuff. (or possibly even influencing you to the opinion that lower value stuff has more negatives than positives)

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

I think the issue at hand is not whether or not someone thinks the question is site-worthy or not (that is a separate issue), but rather the fate of an answer to a question that has been deleted, and the issue I find is Mariano's unwillingness to consider approaches alternative to simply undeleting the question.

---

> well, the point of my post is that there can be a standard: putting the value of the content our users produce above the our beloved byzantine "tensions". I am asking if we are to take such a standard or not, mostly in order to decide if there is any point in answering questions. – Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦ [yesterday](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/deleting-questions-with-answers#comment116382_28168)

If this is truly the point of your post, I must say "yes, I believe we should value the content worth keeping, but no, by no means through keeping them on poor questions."

When the question was deleted by non-OP users, you then [undeleted it](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2712921/timeline#history_cfdcc075-7839-456b-b117-e622ec956247).

But it would seem there is a better option. As the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says,

> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers.

Frankly, you are the moderator here, but there has been no mention as to whether or not you've considered this possibility.

If the question is deleted so merge is not possible, there is nothing stopping you from copying the answer over to the merge candidate.

Also, it has been mentioned to you, multiple times so far, that there is also the option to post your own question and then self-answer, in order to preserve the content you are so concerned with, if a merge candidate does not exist.

Comment: You seem to have not understood what I meant in that «I undeleted as I always do…» line: I am referring exclusively to deletions done by the original poster of the question, in what is always an attempt to cover tracks of cheating or something like that. I have never undeleted a question deleted by votes of *other* users (that I recall, at least… it's been years)

Comment: As for your last paragraph: I know of that possibility (apparently there is a consensus that I am an imbecile that does not know the basic workings of the site, but I really don't mind at all) What I am saying is that I, as a writer of an answer, was not notified when the question was deleted: if I had not had need for the answer myself, I would have never found out that the content was deleted.

Comment: So after making a judgement call that the question was not as bad as to merit reasking a new one or something like that, a user writes an answer. How is that user even to know that he has to take actions to preserve that content?

Comment: Should users book a day of their week to go through their answers to see if a handful of other users have deemed that the question on which it was posted is bad enough that it has to go, along with the answer, in order to preserve them?

Comment: As as for your "Frankly, you are the moderator here, but there has been no mention as to whether or not you've considered this possibility", the explanation is easy: that possibility has absolutely nothing to do with my point. In fact, that quote from the help center actually supports my point: it is addressed at deletion-voters, suggesting they try to preserve the content somehow — exactly what did not happen in this case and, sadly, in many others.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Re: *What I am saying is that I, as a writer of an answer, was not notified when the question was deleted.* This seems to be a bit different from your original post. I'll just point out that since it was upvoted answer, you could probably see it in your reputation tab if you checked the "show removed post" box. There is also a related feature request: [Notify answer OP when answer is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39741).

Comment: If your main concern is how one can easily find their own deleted content, I suppose there are a few methods, see, for example: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) (and some of the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/13948))

Comment: "I am referring exclusively to deletions done by the original poster of the question" Oh, that makes much more sense @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: What I gather from the rest of the comments is follows, and do correct me if I'm wrong. Your concern has now shifted from whether or not we value the content of answers on deleted questions to how one preserves this content as the answerer?

Comment: Well certainly I would start by pointing out taking care of which questions you answer makes some impact. Of course, there will not be agreement between which questions are deemably answerable and which are not, but I personally find the fact that the OP deleted their own post twice after having had it answered, undeleted, and warned to be clear signs that that question may've been a poor question to choose to answer.

Comment: "Should users book a day of their week to go through their answers to see if a handful of other users have deemed that the question on which it was posted is bad enough that it has to go, along with the answer, in order to preserve them?" Well I usually check over my close votes every so often after having cast them, so I see no reason why not. Whether or not you decide your own content is worth checking on is completely up to you. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: @Simply, I don't understand why you seem to think that my concern has "shifted" anywhere... The whole point of the post is that having people delete content ends up requiring people to preserve content — that deletion does not conserve content that it should. I would appreciate it if you corrected the factual mistake in your answer, where you claim that I undid a deletion done by someone other than the OP: I was quite clear in the original post and in other comments in explainkng that non only I did not do that but that I consider that to be an extremely catastrophic bad idea.

Comment: @simply, I think that my content and that generated by others is worth keeping: I am saying that having to periodically check if someone has deleted it is a quite absurd requirement. I will not do that, as I find it a very stupid thing to do. I will probably, when I have time, make available the content somewhere else, somewhere where I don't have to protect it (!) and be gone.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez "I would appreciate it if you corrected the factual mistake in your answer, where you claim that I undid a deletion done by someone other than the OP" Frankly [the timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTdQJ.png) disagrees with you on that one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I never said periodically checking your answers was a requirement at all. I merely said that if you cared so much about it, you would likely do so at your own will...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If you are unsure as to whether or not you have voted to undelete the question 3 times, you can also check [your undelete votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=undelete).

Answer (score 2):

Mariano, I am sort of surprised by your response to this incident.  I have had questions deleted for which I provided perfectly good answers.  My response was to issue a flag - and in all cases, the question was restored.  As a moderator, you should be able to handle this on your own, no?  Or you could at least issue a flag for a fellow moderator.

One reason people might delete a question after it has been answered is to erase a trail.  For example, the question may be a homework question and the student who posted it may be worried that the teacher will find evidence of cheating, so the student deletes the evidence.  Of course, I wonder if any such student ever came back to the horror of their question reappearing.  (I'd love to see that reaction.)

Again, I have no patience for such antics.  Raise a flag, a moderator takes care of it.  Done.

Comment: Mariano did undelete the original's asker's deletion.  Later, after the question's undeletion, it was deleted by three users. After that, Mariano undeleted it again.  Then it was again deleted by three votes from users.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Is there a way to protect the question after x number of reopenenings?

Comment: There doesn't seem to have been any reopenings.  But I suppose you meant "after x number of deletion/undeletions?"

Comment: Yes, I did. ${}{}$

Comment: You are surprised because you think that the point of this post was to get the question undeleted, I guess. But its point is to tell the community that I think that in its quest against "bad questions", which is certainly good, it is killing content which is useful, which is bad: how does anyone —a moderator or a non-moderator— raise a point about policy?

Comment: As I wrote, this is the very first time that after undeleting a question which had been deleted in an act of self-vandalization by someone possibly cheating or something, I find that experienced users delete again the same content. When the actions of our experienced users —coming out of what seems to be quite a consensus— have the same end result with respect to useful content as the actions of someone using the site to cheat and later cover her tracks, we have a problem, and it is slightly more serious than the deletion of an answer. **That** is what this post is about.

Comment: @Mariano  You've had so many "My point is...", veering off your original post.  Please make those doing their best to respond to you in a position in which we're chasing a moving target. Pick your one main point (one question per post).  You keep veering off with ever-changing "points".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: IMO, the best way to raise a point about policy is by directly posting a question about the policy, rather than posting a vaguely related question which you use as a soapbox to ramble on various topics.

Answer (score -7):

The short answer seems to be:

> No.

Comment: Are you aware of the [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) room? There has been some discussion related to the issue you have raised here in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I honestly do not understand what these downvotes mean: they do not agree with the answer in that the downvoters think the answer should be yes (that is usually what downvotes mean in meta)? What I find extraordinary is the vote to delete.

Comment: The tool-tip says: "This answer is not useful." I'd just go with this interpretation.

Comment: I got the impression that this answer is meant to be an unstated rhetorical point, and that the downvotes are meant to condemn that sort of passive-aggressive approach to the debate. But I'm speculating on both points; I'm not particularly confident in either judgment.